# Declare variable of composite type in PostgreSQL using %TYPE

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, types, polymorphism, plpgsql

Question: How can I declare a variable of the same type a parameter in a stored function?

The simple answer is use `%TYPE`, this works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function_1(param1 text)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
    myVariable param1%TYPE;
BEGIN
    return 1;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

But the problem is when `param1` is a composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE comp_type as
(
    field1 text
)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function_2(param1 comp_type)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
    myVariable param1%TYPE;
BEGIN
    return 1;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

This doesn't work:

```
ERROR: type comp_type does not exist [SQL State=42704]
```

So how can I do when `param1` is a composite type?

(Note: Just `myVariable comp_type` is not a good option because my function is *slightly* more complex.)

---

Edited:
I had a mistake on copy&paste, the real error is:

```
ERROR: invalid type name "param1%TYPE"
  Position: 130 [SQL State=42601]
```

And using `param1%ROWTYPE` the error is:

```
ERROR: relation "param1" does not exist
  Where: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "test_function_2" near line 3 [SQL State=42P01]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Use [`%ROWTYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) in that case.</strike>

#### Simple case

Tests by A.H. and DavidEG have shown this won't work. Interesting problem!
You could try a **workaround**. As long as your definition is like the example you can simply resort to

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION test(param1 comp_type)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE AS
$func$ 
DECLARE
   myvar comp_type;
BEGIN
   RETURN 1;
END
$func$;
```

But your real problem is probably not as simple?

#### The real problem

As expected, the real problem turns out to be more complex: a **polymorphic input type**.
**Workaround** for that scenario was harder, but should work flawlessly:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION test(param1 anyelement, OUT a integer, OUT myvar anyelement)
  RETURNS record
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   myvar := $1;    -- myvar has the required type now.
   -- do stuff with myvar.

   myvar := NULL;  -- reset if you don't want to output ..
   a := 1;
END;
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT a FROM test('("foo")'::comp_type); -- just retrieve a, ignore myvar
```

See full output:

```
SELECT * FROM test('("foo")'::comp_type);
```

#### Note for Postgres 9.0+

There has been a crucial update in Postgres 9.0. [The release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/release-9-0.html)

> - Allow input parameters to be assigned values within PL/pgSQL functions
>   (Steve Prentice)
>
> Formerly, input parameters were treated as being declared `CONST`, so
> the function's code could not change their values. This restriction
> has been removed to simplify porting of functions from other DBMSes
> that do not impose the equivalent restriction. An input parameter now
> acts like a local variable initialized to the passed-in value.

In addition to my workaround, you can (ab)use input variables directly now.

#### Dynamic field names

See:

- [How to clone a RECORD in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776613/how-to-clone-a-record-in-postgresql/25815243#25815243)
- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711432/how-to-set-value-of-composite-variable-field-using-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Won't work, "param1.%ROWTYPE" says "relation param1 does not exist". I'm curious whether anyone finds an answer for that.

Comment: I've got the same error with `%ROWTYPE` and `%TYPE`. BTW I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: @Erwin That works, but in the real problem `param1` is `anyelement` so I don't know the type to hardcode it.

Comment: I've tested your second workaround and it seems to work quite good. I tried with standard types, composite types, arrays and no problem. Thanks @Erwin.

Comment: I don't understand how to access `field1` of `param1` or `myvar`. Is this still possible despite the type being `anyelement`?

Comment: @A.H.: Reference field1 by name like a table column: `param1.field1`. As `param1` is declared as `anyelement` the function will allow that call at creation time. Of course, if you hand in a type at call time, that has no `field1`, you trigger an error.