# SQL to return list of fields containing non-NULL data

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, postgresql

How can I return a list of fields from a given table that contain any non-NULL data?

As en example, how could I query the example table below to only return the following three values as they contain something other than NULL.

- LO2_HiddenOrgID
- LO2_BranchOfOrgID
- LO2_ShortName

[image: Example Database]

I'm looking to automate this as much as possible as I have a few thousand fields to inspect.

Also, I'm currently using SQLite while developing, but would happily accept any suggestions specific to SQLite, MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: so the query should return a list of columns in which data is found, rather than the data itself?

Comment: i think it should be done on programming codes if you were going to output only columns having a values.

Comment: @ninesided Yes.  I'm trying to build a list of fields to keep.  Any fields that only have NULL data at this point can be purged.  The data is irrelevant as it will be ported back in later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*So your goal is to get the **list of column names** such that all of them have at least one non-NULL value in any of the rows, right? If so, see below...*

You can't parametrize names of columns in an SQL query, so you'll need to build your SQL text dynamically, in the client language of your choosing. The algorithm would look like this:

1. You'll have to know the list of column names in advance. There are ways to automate retrieving this list in [PostgreSQL](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2005-09/msg00060.php), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) and most other databases.
2. Iterate through this list and for each `column_name` dynamically build the SQL text such as: `SELECT column_name FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1` (see the MySQL [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) and PostgreSQL [LIMIT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/queries-limit.html)).
3. Execute the query above and fetch the result. If has a row in it, add the `column_name` to the **resulting list**.
4. Keep iterating while there are elements in the column name list.

The resulting list now contains columns with at least one non-NULL value.

Comment: You can also use a stored procedure that queries the system catalog, which is a much better solution. You don't have to know anything in advance.

Answer (score 2):

### Fully automated, complete solution for PostgreSQL

Returns all (non-system) tables in all schemas with with all columns that have at least one non-null value.
You must be a superuser (like postgres) to call this function.
Or you a superuser can own the function and it is created with [SECURITY DEFINER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tbl_with_nonull_cols()
  RETURNS TABLE(tbl text, columns text) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rel_id  oid;        -- oid of table
    sch     text;       -- schema name
    cols1   text;       -- columns defined NOT NULL
    cols2   text;       -- other columns
    q       text;       -- for query string
    has_row bool;       -- table has rows?
BEGIN

FOR rel_id, sch, tbl IN
SELECT c.oid            -- AS rel_id
      ,n.nspname        -- as sch
      ,c.relname        -- as tbl
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
LEFT   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  c.relkind = 'r'
AND    n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
AND    n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
AND    n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
AND    pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER  BY 2,3

LOOP
    EXECUTE 'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM '
             || quote_ident(sch) ||'.' || quote_ident(tbl) || ')'
    INTO has_row;

    IF has_row THEN
        -- defined NOT NULL -> must have values.
        SELECT INTO cols1
               string_agg(a.attname,', ')
        FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
        WHERE  a.attrelid = rel_id
        AND    a.attnum > 0
        AND    NOT a.attisdropped
        AND    a.attnotnull;

        SELECT INTO q
               'array_to_string(ARRAY['
                || string_agg('CASE WHEN count(' || quote_ident(a.attname)
                || ') > 0 THEN '''|| a.attname || ''' ELSE NULL END', ', ')
                || '], '', '')'
        FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
        WHERE  a.attrelid = rel_id
        AND    a.attnum > 0
        AND    NOT a.attisdropped
        AND    NOT a.attnotnull;

        IF q IS NOT NULL THEN
            EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || q || '
            FROM  ' || quote_ident(sch) || '.' || quote_ident(tbl)
            INTO cols2;

            columns := COALESCE(cols1 || ', ', '') || cols2;
        ELSE
            columns := COALESCE(cols1, '');
        END IF;

        RETURN NEXT;
    ELSE
        -- no rows, so no columns with non-null values
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_tbl_with_nonull_cols();
       tbl      |                   columns
----------------+----------------------------------
 table1         | id, col1, col7,
 table2         | id, col4, col5, col8, col9, col10
 table5         | some_id
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LO2_HiddenOrgID FROM MyTable WHERE LO2_HiddenOrgID IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT LO2_BranchOfOrgID FROM MyTable WHERE LO2_BranchOfOrgID IS NOT NULL
```

and so on

Comment: I believe he's looking for the column names, not the data

Comment: two queries is the same. he is looking for the script to output only columns not having a null values.

Comment: @Bryan You think it wanted THIS one?

Answer (score 0):

@citricguy: I believe you need all the columns which contains not null data without specifically selecting any columns in the query. Correct me if it is otherwise.

Comment: that's it. but how should he know if the one column doesn't have any value?

Comment: I really only need column names.  I would prefer a list of the columns that contain data I suppose, but I could always easily reverse the list. Data is irrelevant as it will be ported back in later into the new, clean database.

Answer (score 0):

What @xanatos said, but put quotes round the selected column names..

```
SELECT distinct 'LO2_HiddenOrgID' FROM MyTable WHERE LO2_HiddenOrgID IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct 'LO2_BranchOfOrgID' FROM MyTable WHERE LO2_BranchOfOrgID IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct 'LO2_HiddenOtyID' FROM MyTable WHERE LO2_HiddenOtyID IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct 'LO2_ShortName' FROM MyTable WHERE LO2_ShortName IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but this query would return the number of not null items in each column. If you do a check on the values returned, you could output the fields.

`SELECT COUNT(Col1) AS Col1, COUNT(Col2) AS Col2, COUNT(Col3) AS`Col3`,` etc....
`FROM table`
`WHERE table.Col1 IS NOT NULL OR table.Col2 IS NOT NULL OR table.Col3 IS NOT NULL` etc..

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, I would go for something like this, there are clever things that you could do in a more feature rich RDBMS:

```
SELECT 'LO2_HiddenOrgID'
FROM MyTable
WHERE LO2_HiddenOrgID IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT 'LO2_BranchOfOrgID'
FROM MyTable
WHERE LO2_BranchOfOrgID IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT 'LO2_HiddenOtyID'
FROM MyTable
WHERE LO2_HiddenOtyID IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
```

It should be possible to generate the above query dynamically, based on meta-data stored in the SQLite data dictionary:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE tbl_name = 'MyTable' 
AND type = 'table'
```