# How to get a list of all date columns which have 'NULL' in all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server with 369 columns.

Out of these 369, 127 columns are of type `date`, and some of those 127 date columns have `null` values in all rows.

How do I get the list of these `date` columns with `NULL` values in all rows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791361/sql-to-return-list-of-fields-containing-non-null-data

Comment: _"I have a table with 369 columns"_ OMG, have you ever heard of [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?

Comment: Are you sure you want "the list of these date columns with NULL values in all **rows**"? And not the rows where all date columns are NULL for example? The first one is easy, the last one also, but a lot of typing..

Comment: `MAX(column)` or `MIN(column)` will only return `NULL` if all rows have `NULL` in column `column`. Now you just have to repeat that 127 times, and ask yourself how you let things get to this point.

Answer (score 0):

This may be very resource-heavy operation, depending on table size, but this should do it:

Generate some SQL:

```
select 
    TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, column_name, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, 
    cmd = 'case when count(*)=sum(case when [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] is null then 1 else 0 end) then 1 else 0 end as [' + COLUMN_NAME + '__isAllNulls],'
from information_schema.columns
where 1=1
    and DATA_TYPE like '%date%'
    and TABLE_NAME = '<yourtablename>'
```

Then write the select:

```
select
    <paste CMD from above results>
from <yourtablename>
```

EDIT2: sample final query after pasting generated CMD column would look like this:

```
select
    case when count(*)=sum(case when [DateAdded] is not null then 1 else 0 end) then 1 else 0 end as [DateAdded__isAllNulls],
    case when count(*)=sum(case when [DateModified] is null then 1 else 0 end) then 1 else 0 end as [DateModified__isAllNulls],
    case when count(*)=sum(case when [DateClosed] is null then 1 else 0 end) then 1 else 0 end as [DateClosed__isAllNulls]
from yourtable
```

The result should be something like:

```
DateAdded__isAllNulls    DateModified__isAllNulls    DateClosed__isAllNulls
1                        0                           0
```

EDIT: Simple `min()` or `max()` would be better than my `case when count(*)=sum(case ...` , as @Damien_the_Unbeliever suggested in his comment, but still you can use my code to generate the sql.

Comment: the 1=1 in Where clause it not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I have ran the first query and it gave me the following result like this:

Comment: Thanks, I have ran the first query and it gave me the following result like this:                                                               TABLE_CATALOG TABLE_SCHEMA TABLE_NAME   COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE IS_NULLABLE cmd. I dndnt get what you want me to do with the second "select
    <paste CMD from above results>
from <yourtablename>".  Another issue is that those datefield columns are stored in the table as varchar datatype

Comment: @Jade Yes, I know. Code indentation and newlines are not necessary either :)

Comment: @user3227041 You only need to use CMD column in final query. Please see EDIT2. You didn't say that you store date in varchar columns. In this case you must find some way to identify those columns. By column name, or text format.

Comment: It wasn't me that stored the date in varchar just got this job and it happens that most of my work is center on this table. what suggestion can I give my boss. this is given me alot of problems