# How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, return-query

I have this function in PostgreSQL, but I don't know how to return the result of the query:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wordFrequency(maxTokens INTEGER)
  RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$$
BEGIN
  SELECT text, count(*), 100 / maxTokens * count(*)
  FROM (
    SELECT text
    FROM token
    WHERE chartype = 'ALPHABETIC'
    LIMIT maxTokens
  ) AS tokens
  GROUP BY text
  ORDER BY count DESC
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I don't know how to return the result of the query inside the PostgreSQL function.

I found that the return type should be `SETOF RECORD`, right? But the return command is not right.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Why do you count them; do you have duplicate tokens in your token TABLE? Also: please add the table definition to your question.

Comment: Is this your entire function? If you don't have any other statements in the function, you should just make it `LANGUAGE SQL`.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Use **[`RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION word_frequency(_max_tokens int)
  RETURNS TABLE (txt   text   -- also visible as OUT param in function body
               , cnt   bigint
               , ratio bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT t.txt
        , count(*) AS cnt                 -- column alias only visible in this query
        , (count(*) * 100) / _max_tokens  -- I added parentheses
   FROM  (
      SELECT t.txt
      FROM   token t
      WHERE  t.chartype = 'ALPHABETIC'
      LIMIT  _max_tokens
      ) t
   GROUP  BY t.txt
   ORDER  BY cnt DESC;                    -- potential ambiguity 
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM word_frequency(123);
```

Defining the return type explicitly is much more practical than returning a generic `record`. This way you don't have to provide a column definition list with every function call. [**`RETURNS TABLE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) is one way to do that. There are others. Data types of `OUT` parameters have to match exactly what is returned by the query.

Choose names for `OUT` parameters carefully. They are visible in the function body almost anywhere. Table-qualify columns of the same name to avoid conflicts or unexpected results. I did that for all columns in my example.

But note the potential **naming conflict** between the `OUT` parameter `cnt` and the column alias of the same name. In this particular case (`RETURN QUERY SELECT ...`) Postgres uses the column alias over the `OUT` parameter either way. This can be ambiguous in other contexts, though. There are various ways to avoid any confusion:

1. Use the ordinal position of the item in the SELECT list: `ORDER BY 2 DESC`. Example:

   - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
2. Repeat the expression `ORDER BY count(*)`.
3. (Not required here.) Set the configuration parameter `plpgsql.variable_conflict` or use the special command `#variable_conflict error | use_variable | use_column` in the function. See:

   - [Naming conflict between function parameter and result of JOIN with USING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/105831/3684)

Don't use "text" or "count" as column names. Both are legal to use in Postgres, but "count" is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in standard SQL and a basic function name and "text" is a basic data type. Can lead to confusing errors. I use `txt` and `cnt` in my examples, you may want more explicit names.

Added a missing `;` and corrected a syntax error in the header. `(_max_tokens int)`, not `(int maxTokens)` - data type after name.

While working with integer division, it's better to multiply first and divide later, to minimize the rounding error. Or work with `numeric` or a floating point type. See below.

#### Alternative

This is what I *think* your query should actually look like (calculating a *relative share per token*):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION word_frequency(_max_tokens int)
  RETURNS TABLE (txt            text
               , abs_cnt        bigint
               , relative_share numeric)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT t.txt, t.cnt
        , round((t.cnt * 100) / (sum(t.cnt) OVER ()), 2)  -- AS relative_share
   FROM  (
      SELECT t.txt, count(*) AS cnt
      FROM   token t
      WHERE  t.chartype = 'ALPHABETIC'
      GROUP  BY t.txt
      ORDER  BY cnt DESC
      LIMIT  _max_tokens
      ) t
   ORDER  BY t.cnt DESC;
END
$func$;
```

The expression `sum(t.cnt) OVER ()` is a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). You *could* use a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) instead of the subquery. Pretty, but a subquery is typically cheaper in simple cases like this one (mostly before Postgres 12).

A final [explicit `RETURN` statement is *not* required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782641/939860) (but allowed) when working with `OUT` parameters or `RETURNS TABLE` (which makes implicit use of `OUT` parameters).

[`round()` with two parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) only works for **[`numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)** types. `count()` in the subquery produces a `bigint` result and a `sum()` over this `bigint` produces a `numeric` result, thus we deal with a `numeric` number automatically and everything just falls into place.

Comment: Very thanks to your answer and corrections. Is working fine now (I only changed the ratio type to numeric).

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição Cool! I added a version that may or may not answer an additional question that you haven't actually asked. ;)

Comment: Nice, the only thing is I think you need a `RETURN;` before that `END;`, at least I did - but I'm doing a UNION so I'm not sure if that makes it different.

Comment: @yekta: I added some information concerning the role of `RETURN`. Fixed an unrelated error and added some improvements while being at it.

Comment: What is the way to do this when you don't want to constrain what is in Return TABLE(). IE RETURN TABLE(*) ?

Comment: @Nick: You might be looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864911/return-setof-rows-from-postgresql-function/17865708#17865708 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret/8611675#8611675 or even this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557

Answer (score 9):

Please see the following link for documentation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html

Example:

```sql
    CREATE FUNCTION sum_n_product_with_tab (x int)
    RETURNS TABLE(sum int, product int) AS $$
        SELECT $1 + tab.y, $1 * tab.y FROM tab;
    $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: Yes, better to **use "pure SQL"** whenever you can. You can use two or more commands (SELECT's, INSERTS, etc.), only the last one is the return value. A workaround for procedural "dependent step by step" is to use a chain of clauses in a  WITH. For example `WITH t1 as (SELECT etc1), t2 as (SELECT etc2 from t1)  SELECT result FROM t2;`

Comment: @PeterKrauss may I ask why? Are there any references recommending SQL over PLPGSQL?

Comment: Hi @Rafs, yes... It's not easy to find exactly what PostgreSQL does nowadays, but is the **JIT optimizer** that, for example, reuse SQL code in a SQL-VIEW, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/jit-reason.html

Answer (score 0):

For example, you create `person` table, then insert 2 rows into it as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  age INT
);

INSERT INTO person (id, name, age) 
VALUES (1, 'John', 27), (2, 'David', 32);
```

Now, you can create `my_func()` with a `RETURN QUERY` statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF person AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM person; -- Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` returns 2 rows as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT * FROM my_func();
 id | name  | age
----+-------+-----
  1 | John  |  27
  2 | David |  32
(2 rows)
```

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
   my_func
--------------
 (1,John,27)
 (2,David,32)
(2 rows)
```