# Return SETOF rows from PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.2

I have a situation where I want to return the join between two views. and that's a lot of columns. It was pretty easy in sql server. But in PostgreSQL when I do the join. I get the error "a column definition list is required".

Is there any way I can bypass this, I don't want to provide the definitions of returning columns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION functionA(username character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying, databaseobject character varying DEFAULT ''::character varying)
  RETURNS SETOF ???? AS
$BODY$
Declare 
SqlString varchar(4000) = '';
BEGIN
IF(UserName = '*') THEN
   Begin
   SqlString  := 'select * from view1 left join ' + databaseobject  + ' as view2 on view1.id = view2.id';
   End;
ELSE
    Begin
    SqlString := 'select * from view3 left join ' + databaseobject  + ' as view2 on view3.id = view2.id';
    End;
END IF; 
execute (SqlString  );
END;
$BODY$
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### Sanitize function

What you currently have can be simplified / sanitized to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_a (username text = '', databaseobject text = '')
  RETURNS ????
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
   format ('SELECT * FROM %s v1 LEFT JOIN %I v2 USING (id)'
         , CASE WHEN username = '*' THEN 'view1' ELSE 'view3' END
         , databaseobject);
END
$func$;
```

You only need additional instances of [`BEGIN ... END` in the function body](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) to start separate code blocks with their own scope, which is rarely needed.

The standard SQL concatenation operator is `||`. `+` is a "creative" addition of your former vendor.

Don't use [CaMeL-case identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) unless you double-quote them. Best don't use them at all See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

`varchar(4000)` is also tailored to a specific limitation of SQL Server. It has no specific significance in Postgres. Only use `varchar(4000)` if you actually need a limit of 4000 characters. I would just use [`text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) - except that we don't need any variables *at all* here, after simplifying the function.

If you have not used `format()`, yet, [consult the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

#### Return type

Now, for your actual question: The return type for a dynamic query can be tricky since SQL requires that to be declared at call time at the latest. If you have a table or view or composite type in your database already matching the column definition list, you can just use that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS SETOF my_view AS
...
```

Else, spell the column definition list with out with (simplest) `RETURNS TABLE`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS TABLE (col1 int, col2 text, ...) AS
...
```

If you are making the row type up as you go, you can return anonymous records:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
...
```

But then you have to provide a column definition list with every call, so I hardly ever use that.

I wouldn't use `SELECT *` to begin with. Use a definitive list of columns to return and declare your return type accordingly:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_a(username text = '', databaseobject text = '')
  RETURNS TABLE(col1 int, col2 text, col3 date)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
   format ($f$SELECT v1.col1, v1.col2, v2.col3
              FROM %s v1 LEFT JOIN %I v2 USING (id)$f$
         , CASE WHEN username = '*' THEN 'view1' ELSE 'view3' END
         , databaseobject);
END
$func$;
```

For completely dynamic queries, consider building the query in your client to begin with, instead of using a function.

You need to understand basics first:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)
- [PL/pgSQL in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)

Then there are more advanced options with [polymorphic types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC), which allow you to pass the return type at call time. More in the last chapter of:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: What if Returns is table and only where condition is coming from application e.g. https://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html?

Comment: @MaulikModi: If it's always the same return type, that's answered above. If only *values* in the `WHERE` clause change, it's a plain query with parameters. Maybe just an SQL function, or a prepared statement. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51052998/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771561/939860 Else, it depends - probably still dynamic SQL. Ask a new *question*, comments are not the place.