# Return a table of custom type in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function like that

```
foo() RETURNS TABLE(col1,col2,col3) AS....
```

But I want to change it for return a custom type

```
CREATE TYPE mytype AS
   (col1,col2,col3);
```

And:

```
foo() RETURNS mytype AS....
```

But I don't know how can I do it

Comment: This should be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17865708/939860

Comment: Thank you! My next question was how could iterate over a custom type into a function but I can see in your answer that in this case I must to return a table(col1,col2....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `returns setof` with a custom type:

```
create function foo() 
  returns setof mytype
as
...
```