# Can I use a return type of a table plus one column from a different table?

Tags: postgresql, set-returning-functions

I have a PostgreSQL function returning all columns of `table1`, and `id` of `table2`. I'd rather not type out each of the fields for a new return type (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17865708/2662176) in the `RETURNS TABLE` example), as there are nine columns in this table, and I'll be doing this multiple times for different similar queries. (The query is an `INNER JOIN`.)

I'd like to do something like:

```
...
RETURNS SETOF schema.table1 || schema.table2.id
...
$$
etc
$$
```

Is there an simple way to accomplish this with the table name/type, or must I type out each column and type again?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve that by defining the function return type like this:

```
RETURNS TABLE (
   t1    schema.table1,
   t2_id bigint
)
```

Then you will only get two columns in the result set, but the first column is of the composite type that corresponds to `table1`, and you can access its members like this:

```
SELECT (t1).*, t2_id FROM func();
```

Comment: You should add that this returns only two columns (the first one being a record type) not all columns of table1 plus one additional column. Expanding the columns needs to be done when selecting from the function: `select (t1).*, t2_id from the_function()`

Comment: ... so if I call this from a server function, I would need to do another SQL query to extract the data from the returned data? This implementation is in Go: normally the data is extracted from the returned psql command using the .Scan() method, passing fields of appropriate types and the method fills the Go variables. Seems like this returning a compound column (a table inside of a column), that table inside the column would need processing [again] by the psql object within Go...

Comment: I don't see why. You need a `SELECT` anyway to get the function result. The `SELECT` statement in my answer should return the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html):

```
postgres=# create table t1(a int, b int);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# create table t2(c int) inherits(t1);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# \d t2
                  Table "public.t2"
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| a      | integer |           |          |         |
| b      | integer |           |          |         |
| c      | integer |           |          |         |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
Inherits: t1
```

Comment: These tables need to be set up during database setup though, and not declared on the fly, correct?

Comment: I don't understand to question - it's table - so you can declare it everywhere where you can declare table