# How to dynamically SELECT from manually partitioned table

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, union-all, table-partitioning

Suppose I have table of tenants like so;

```sql
CREATE TABLE tenants (
  name varchar(50)
)
```

And for each tenant, I have a corresponding table called `{tenants.name}_entities`, so for example for `tenant_a` I would have the following table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tenant_a_entities {
  id uuid,
  last_updated timestamp
}
```

Is there a way I can create a query with the following structure? (using create table syntax to show what I'm looking for)

```sql
CREATE TABLE all_tenant_entities {
  tenant_name varchar(50),
  id uuid,
  last_updated timestamp
}
```

--

I do understand this is a strange DB layout, I'm playing around with [foreign data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-foreign-data.html) in Postgres to federate foreign databases.

Comment: Why aren't you using [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)

Comment: Assume a database per tenant setup and I want to monitor this setup, I have one database that federates the others via foreign tables. Each tenant has an `entities` table. Hence I have many tables prefixed by their tenant name (or origin db) in this _federated view_ database

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider [**declarative partitioning**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) for your relational design? List partitioning for your case, with `PARTITION BY LIST` ...

---

To answer the question at hand:

You don't need the table `tenants` for the query at all, just the detail tables. And one way or another you'll end up with `UNION ALL` to stitch them together.

```sql
SELECT 'a' AS tenant_name, id, last_updated FROM tenant_a_entities 
UNION ALL SELECT 'b', id, last_updated FROM tenant_b_entities 
...
```

You *can* add the name dynamically, like:

```sql
SELECT tableoid::regclass::text, id, last_updated FROM tenant_a_entities 
UNION ALL SELECT tableoid::regclass::text, id, last_updated FROM tenant_a_entities
...
```

See:

- [Get the name of a row's source table when querying the parent it inherits from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580352/get-the-name-of-a-rows-source-table-when-querying-the-parent-it-inherits-from/24581769#24581769)

But it's cheaper to add a constant name while **building the query dynamically** in your case (the first code example) - like this, for example:

```sql
SELECT string_agg(format('SELECT %L AS tenant_name, id, last_updated FROM %I' 
                        , split_part(tablename, '_', 2)
                        , tablename)
                  , E'\nUNION ALL '
                 ORDER BY tablename)  -- optional order
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE  schemaname = 'public'  -- actual schema name
AND    tablename LIKE 'tenant\_%\_entities';
```

Tenant names cannot contain `_`, or you have to do more.

Related:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

You can wrap it in a custom function to make it completely dynamic:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_all_tenant_entities()
  RETURNS TABLE(tenant_name text, id uuid, last_updated timestamp)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
   (
   SELECT string_agg(format('SELECT %L AS tn, id, last_updated FROM %I' 
                           , split_part(tablename, '_', 2)
                           , tablename)
                     , E'\nUNION ALL '
                    ORDER BY tablename)  -- optional order
   FROM   pg_tables
   WHERE  schemaname = 'public'  -- your schema name here
   AND    tablename LIKE 'tenant\_%\_entities'
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.f_all_tenant_entities();
```

You can use this set-returning function (a.k.a "table-function") just like a table in most contexts in SQL.

Related:

- [How to UNION a list of tables retrieved from another table with a single query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56830267/how-to-union-a-list-of-tables-retrieved-from-another-table-with-a-single-query/56830524#56830524)
- [Simulate CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql/18389184#18389184)
- [Function to loop through and select data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618672/function-to-loop-through-and-select-data-from-multiple-tables/24621496#24621496)

Note that `RETIRN QUERY` does not allow parallel queriies before Postgres 14. [The  release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-14.html)

> Allow plpgsql's RETURN QUERY to execute its query using parallelism (Tom Lane)