# Include parameter in function to UNION multiple PostgreSQL tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have developed a function to `UNION ALL` tables from a list of table names (a table called `tablelist` below) inspired by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56830267/how-to-union-a-list-of-tables-retrieved-from-another-table-with-a-single-query).

The initial function just returns a selection, but now I'd like to write a new table with a name taken from a parameter `new_table_name`.

I'm struggling with the syntax to insert the parameter into the `DROP TABLE` AND `CREATE TABLE` statements. Here's one of the attempts which returns `ERROR:  mismatched parentheses at or near ";"`

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_multi_union(text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_multi_union(new_tab_name text)
  RETURNS Table (my_id int, metric double precision, geom geometry)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
   (
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS working.'' || new_tab_name || '';
   CREATE TABLE working.'' || new_tab_name || '' AS (
   SELECT string_agg(format('SELECT * FROM %s', tbl), ' UNION ALL ')
   FROM (SELECT tbl FROM working.tablelist) sub 
    )
   );
END
$func$;
```

Comment: RETURN QUERY EXECUTE can execute just one single query, not multiple. And you have a DROP and a CREATE statement, that makes two. Place the DROP statement before the RETURN part and you're fine.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I moved `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS working.'' || new_tab_name || '';` between `BEGIN` and `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`. Now gives `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "''"
LINE 8:     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS working.'' || new_tab_name || '';` Something wrong with syntax for calling parameter.

Comment: Use something like this:    EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS working.%I', new_tab_name); -- avoid SQL injection
However, I don't think this functions will do you want it to do, it creates a table with a single record holding a SQL statement. Is that what you want?

Comment: @FrankHeikens using `format` passes the `DROP` statement but falls over @ `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 11:    CREATE TABLE working.'' || new_tab_name || '' AS (` My aim is to create a table that holds the contents of multiple `UNION ALL`s from a list of table names `tablelist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_multi_union(text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_multi_union(new_tab_name text)
  RETURNS void -- nothing to return
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _sql            TEXT;
BEGIN
    _sql    := format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS working.%I;', new_tab_name); -- avoid SQL injection
    EXECUTE _sql;

    _sql    :=  'SELECT string_agg(format(''SELECT * FROM %I'', tbl), '' UNION ALL '')
                FROM (SELECT tbl FROM working.tablelist) sub;';
    EXECUTE _sql 
        INTO _sql; -- overwrite current _sql content

    _sql    := format('CREATE TABLE working.%I AS %s;', new_tab_name, _sql);
    EXECUTE _sql;
   
END
$func$;
```

I would replace the * in the SELECT statement with the columns that you need.

Comment: That worked but I had to swap `format(''SELECT * FROM %I'', tbl)` to `format(''SELECT * FROM %s'', tbl)` because the relation wasn't recognised with double quotes wrapping.

Comment: @mark: That means the content in your table was wrong. Using %s could cause new problems. When the content matches the table name, %I is the only thing you need to be save.

Comment: what do you mean by content of the table?

Comment: In your table working.tablelist you have a column tbl. The content in there must match the exact name of the tables you want to use in your SELECT statement. If you have a table "foo" (lower case), you should store it as "foo" and not "Foo" with an upper case. Also no additional spaces or other stuff, it has to match 100%.