Query with CTE yields different results when nested in PL/pgSQL function?
I have 2 identical queries except for one being inside a PL/pgSQL function and the other outside a function, producing different results.
Function is:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_customer_daily_consumption(
    in_group_id bigint,
    in_customer_id bigint,
    in_start_date timestamp without time zone,
    in_end_date timestamp without time zone)
    RETURNS TABLE(customer_id bigint, customer_name character varying, serial_number character varying, address character varying, current_reading double precision, yesterday_reading double precision, consumption_date timestamp without time zone, previous_day timestamp without time zone, units_consumed double precision) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
declare
    rec record;
    sql_query text;
begin
sql_query := 'WITH 
    date_range AS (
        SELECT 
            generate_series(''' || in_start_date || '''::timestamp - interval ''1 day'', ''' || in_end_date || '''::timestamp, ''1 day''::interval)::date AS report_date
    ),
    assetSerialTbl AS
    (select max(smt_asset.serial_number) as serial_number, smt_asset.customer_id from  smt_asset 
where  smt_asset.group_id= ' ||in_group_id ;
sql_query :=sql_query||' group by smt_asset.customer_id order by smt_asset.customer_id ),

assetReadings AS
    (select  asset_id, max(number_of_units) as assetReading,date_range.report_date,
  customer_id, group_id
 from smt_raw_data rawData, date_range 
     
     where group_id = '||in_group_id ;
     
     sql_query :=sql_query||' AND rawData.modified_date >= date_range.report_date::timestamp 
            AND rawData.modified_date < (date_range.report_date + 1)::timestamp -- Consider time range from 00:00:00 to 11:59:59
 group by  asset_id,date_range.report_date,customer_id,group_id),
 
 customerAssetTbl AS
 (select sum(assetReadings.assetReading) as customerReading,smt_customer.customer_id,assetReadings.report_date
  from smt_customer  join assetReadings on smt_customer.customer_id= assetReadings.customer_id
 group by smt_customer.customer_id,assetReadings.report_date
 order by customer_id
 ),
    
customerReading  AS
   ( SELECT 
        cust.customer_id, 
        cont.full_name AS customer_name,
        cont.first_name AS customer_first_name,
        assetSerialTbl.serial_number AS serial_number,
        loc.address_line1,
        customerAssetTbl.report_date AS reading_date,
        customerAssetTbl.customerReading AS units_consumed,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY customerAssetTbl.report_date) AS row_num
    FROM 
         smt_customer cust
        JOIN smt_contact cont ON cont.customer_id = cust.customer_id
        JOIN assetSerialTbl ON assetSerialTbl.customer_id= cust.customer_id
        LEFT JOIN smt_location loc ON loc.customer_id = cust.customer_id       
        JOIN customerAssetTbl ON  customerAssetTbl.customer_id = cust.customer_id
     WHERE 
        cust.group_id = '||in_group_id ;

IF in_customer_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    sql_query := sql_query || ' AND cust.customer_id = ' || in_customer_id ;
END IF;

sql_query :=sql_query || ' GROUP BY cust.customer_id, cont.full_name, cont.first_name, assetSerialTbl.serial_number, loc.address_line1, 
customerAssetTbl.report_date,customerAssetTbl.customerReading
ORDER BY cust.customer_id, customerAssetTbl.report_date),

consumptionTable as(
select  i.customer_id,i.serial_number,date(i.reading_date),date(i.reading_date - interval  ''1 day'') AS previous_day, i.units_consumed as current_reading, iprev.units_consumed as yesterday_reading,
    i.customer_name,i.customer_first_name,i.address_line1,
         ROUND((i.units_consumed - iprev.units_consumed)::numeric,2)as diff
from customerReading i left join
     customerReading iprev
     on iprev.row_num = i.row_num-1
     AND i.customer_id=iprev.customer_id

group by i.customer_id,i.serial_number, date(i.reading_date), i.units_consumed, iprev.units_consumed,i.customer_name,i.customer_first_name,i.address_line1)

select * from consumptionTable where diff IS NOT NULL and diff >=0 ';

raise notice 'sql_query: %', sql_query;

FOR rec IN EXECUTE sql_query
LOOP   
    customer_id := rec.customer_id;
    customer_name := rec.customer_name;  
    serial_number := rec.serial_number;
    address := rec.address_line1; -- No need to show asset-specific information
    current_reading := rec.current_reading;
    yesterday_reading := rec.yesterday_reading;     
    consumption_date:=rec.date;
    previous_day=rec.previous_day;
    units_consumed := rec.diff;    
    
    RETURN NEXT;
END LOOP;
end;
$BODY$;

And the underlying with query is:
WITH 
    date_range AS (
        SELECT 
            generate_series(
    '2024-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp,
    '2024-03-31 00:00:00'::timestamp,
    '1 day'
) ::date AS report_date
    ),
    assetSerialTbl AS
    (select max(smt_asset.serial_number) as serial_number, smt_asset.customer_id from  smt_asset 
where  smt_asset.group_id= 1000073 group by smt_asset.customer_id order by smt_asset.customer_id
 ),

assetReadings AS
    (select  asset_id, max(number_of_units) as assetReading,date_range.report_date,
  customer_id, group_id
 from smt_raw_data rawData, date_range 
     
     where group_id = '1000073' AND rawData.modified_date >= date_range.report_date::timestamp 
            AND rawData.modified_date < (date_range.report_date + 1)::timestamp 
 group by  asset_id,date_range.report_date,customer_id,group_id ),
 
 customerAssetTbl AS
 (select sum(assetReadings.assetReading) as customerReading,smt_customer.customer_id,assetReadings.report_date
  from smt_customer  join assetReadings on smt_customer.customer_id= assetReadings.customer_id
 group by smt_customer.customer_id,assetReadings.report_date
 order by customer_id
 ),
 
 customerReading  AS
   ( SELECT 
        
        cust.customer_id, 
        cont.full_name AS customer_name,
        cont.first_name AS customer_first_name,
        assetSerialTbl.serial_number AS serial_number,
        loc.address_line1,
        customerAssetTbl.report_date AS reading_date,
        customerAssetTbl.customerReading AS units_consumed,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY customerAssetTbl.report_date) AS row_num
    FROM 
         smt_customer cust
        JOIN smt_contact cont ON cont.customer_id = cust.customer_id
        JOIN assetSerialTbl ON assetSerialTbl.customer_id= cust.customer_id
        LEFT JOIN smt_location loc ON loc.customer_id = cust.customer_id       
        JOIN customerAssetTbl ON  customerAssetTbl.customer_id = cust.customer_id
     WHERE 
        cust.group_id = '1000073'  AND cust.customer_id = 3000265 
   GROUP BY cust.customer_id, cont.full_name, cont.first_name, assetSerialTbl.serial_number, loc.address_line1, 
customerAssetTbl.report_date,customerAssetTbl.customerReading
ORDER BY cust.customer_id, customerAssetTbl.report_date),
 

consumptionTable as(
select  i.customer_id,i.serial_number,date(i.reading_date),date(i.reading_date - interval  '1 day') AS previous_day, i.units_consumed as current_reading, iprev.units_consumed as yesterday_reading,
    i.customer_name,i.customer_first_name,i.address_line1,
         ROUND((i.units_consumed - iprev.units_consumed)::numeric,2)as diff
from customerReading i left join
     customerReading iprev
     on iprev.row_num = i.row_num-1
     AND i.customer_id=iprev.customer_id

group by i.customer_id,i.serial_number, date(i.reading_date), i.units_consumed, iprev.units_consumed,i.customer_name,i.customer_first_name,i.address_line1)

select * from customerReading;

This gives correct result for customer 300063:
select * from get_customer_daily_consumption(1000073, 300063, '23-07-2024 00:00:00', '30-07-2024 00:00:00');

Here 1000073 is group_id, having many customers inside. 300063 is customer_id, and I am trying to find the consumption per day.
However, if I run:
select * from get_customer_daily_consumption(1000073, null, '23-07-2024 00:00:00', '30-07-2024 00:00:00');

to get the value for all customers of the group, keeping customer ID null, it gives wrong result i.e null.
Surprising: if I run the WITH query after putting the hard coded data, it works in all scenarios.
Any hint on what could be the reason?

Unrelated but you do not need dynamic SQL for that. Replace the conditional sql_query := sql_query || ' AND cust.customer_id = ' || in_customer_id; with unconditional and coalesce(cust.customer_id = in_customer_id, true) and use  the arguments within the query. No sql_query text, no execute, just a plain (though complex) query.

Where did '2024-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp and '2024-03-31 00:00:00'::timestamp come from?

This is too convoluted for a question. You'll need professional (paid) assistance. For starters: concatenate your query string safely with format() and use RETURN QUERY EXECUTE. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386034/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17865708/939860
