# Converting the result of a dynamic query to json

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to convert a dynamic query result into `json` and then return that `json` as the result of this function (this is a simplified version, the `WHERE` clause in my actual code is considerably longer).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data_as_json(tbl regclass, p_version_id integer)
  RETURNS json AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN to_json( EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM '|| tbl
                         || ' WHERE version_id = p_budget_version_id' );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, this code results in a `type "execute" does not exist` error.
How do I run the dynamic query, and then convert the result to JSON?

Comment: check http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql - isn't "select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))" example what you´re looking for?

Comment: That doesn't take the dynamic portion of the question into account (but the "array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json" might help. Thanks!)

Comment: for the dynamic part, don't you have to use return query? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql

Comment: not in this instance, because I'm not returning a SETOF

Comment: I see... you're returning a big string... :-(

Answer (score 3):

If you were returning `SETOF` you'd need to use the `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` construct, producing a dynamic query that returns what you want. Since you're not, use regular `EXECUTE ... INTO` a variable that you then return.

Untested, but in vaguely the right direction:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data_as_json(tbl regclass, p_version_id integer) RETURNS json AS $$
DECLARE
    my_result json;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT to_json(*) FROM %I WHERE version_id = p_budget_version_id',tbl) INTO my_result;
    RETURN my_result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that returns me an error of "ERROR: cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function" (I'd tried something similar previously)

Comment: @RodeoClown Try amended version above. Again, untested so you might need to fix up any details.

Comment: Thanks Craig. It still doesn't like the `RETURN QUERY` bit, because it's returning JSON, not a SETOF XXX

Comment: @RodeoClown There's no `RETURN QUERY` there in the updated version. Look again?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that - the comment must have updated, but not the post for some reason. I'll try it tomorrow morning. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What [Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398670/craig-ringer) wrote. But a somewhat different solution with additional fixes:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data_as_json(tbl regclass
                                          , p_version_id integer
                                          , OUT my_result json)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
      'SELECT to_json(*) FROM %s
       WHERE  version_id = $1', tbl)
   INTO  my_result
   USING p_version_id;
END
$func$;
```

Simplest with an [**`OUT`** parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-OUTPUT-PARAMETERS). You can `SELECT INTO` that  directly and be done.

The object identifier type [`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) is quoted automatically (if needed) when output as `text` (automatically). For this, [use **`%s`** with `format()`, not `%I`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

I think the parameter `p_version_id` has been overlooked so far. I suspect a typo in the original code ("p_budget_version_id") combined with invalid syntax. I suggest the `USING` construct with `EXECUTE`. See:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)

Comment: Yeah, there was definitely a typo there. Thanks.