# Make dynamic INSERT inside function more readable

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a user defined Postgres function that does dynamic `INSERT`. Code is unreadable and it's quite hard to modify it due to string escapes. Is there a way to make it look better?

Here is my code, some parts omitted for brevity:

```
BEGIN
    -- some code

    -- escape nightmare for teammates goes here

EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || _table || E'(col1, col2, col3)  VALUES (\'' || _col1 ||
                E'\', \'' || _col2 || E'\''||  E', \'' || _col3::text ||E'\') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING code' INTO _code;

    -- more code
END
```

Is there a way to simplify things like `E'\', \''`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`format()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT), like [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029453/richard-huxton) already instructed. That's not only more readable, it also fixes the glaring SQL injection problem of your original.

What's more, don't concatenate *values* at all. Pass them as values with the `USING` clause:

```
EXECUTE format(
   'INSERT INTO %I (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
    RETURNING code', _table)
INTO  _code
USING _col1, _col2, _col3::text;  -- do you need to cast?
```

To be sure, use a schema-qualified table name - which cannot be passed as single identifier like in the above code. Schema and table name have to be quoted separately. See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [Converting the result of a dynamic query to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592116/converting-the-result-of-a-dynamic-query-to-json/21607470#21607470)
- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

And be sure to understand and use **dollar-quoting**:

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql/12172353#12172353)
- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Answer (score 1):

Use [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

```
format('INSERT INTO %I (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (%L,%L,%L)', _table, _col1, _col2, _col3);
```

Comment: I have issues with escaping strings when using format and %L, I've updated question.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is add comments - specifically what the resulting query looks like. You cannot alter the way the code works, and shouldn't have to very often, when someone does knowing the end result will make it a lot easier to understand how the code builds it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's covered with a bunch of unit-tests. It's clear what it does, but it's hard to modify it due to escape boilerplate.