# Function should return datatype suitable in target for IN

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

Say I have a table `married_name_changes` of names

```
maiden_name  married_name
Jones        Smith
Brown        Perez
Walker       Wilson
```

and I want to create a function that allows queries like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, cellular_phone
FROM guest_list
WHERE last_name IN last_names_including('Lee', 'Perez', 'Wilson')
```

that would return all records with last name Lee, Perez, Wilson, Brown or Walker.

The function definition below allows for a similar query

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, cellular_phone
FROM guest_list
WHERE last_name IN (SELECT * FROM last_names_including('Lee', 'Perez', 'Wilson'))
```

but I would really rather have the neater syntax in the former query.  How can I achieve that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_names_including(last_names_in VARIADIC TEXT[])
RETURNS SETOF TEXT AS
$BODY$
  SELECT maiden_name AS last_name
   FROM married_name_changes
   WHERE married_name= ANY (last_names_in)
  UNION SELECT UNNEST( last_names_in ) AS last_name;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE
  COST 25;
```

I did try converting to *plpgsql* and using `RETURN QUERY` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql) without luck.

Comment: Why do you use function in the first place? Stick your parameters directly in the query and you're done. KISS: Keep it short and simple

Comment: @Frank:  Fair point -- this is a toy [MWE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) version of the real problem, exhibiting the behavior that gives rise to my question.

Comment: FWIW this is for postgresql 9.3.1

Comment: Return an array and use = ANY() instead of IN(). ANY() accepts an array as input parameter http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18486

Comment: According to the docs,for ANY, "The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given operator, which must yield a Boolean result. "   This seems like it might play poorly with the optimizer on large queries.  In addition I have some extra motives for avoiding returning an ARRAY.  Is what I am asking known to be impossible?

Comment: No, you can't have the syntax for the first query at all. Unless you are willing to edit the source code of PostgreSQL to allow it. Using `IN (SELECT ...)` or `=ANY(...)` seems more sensitive. If you are worried about performance, you should post your real problem, as this function seems poorly and unneeded, basic reinvent `JOIN`.

Comment: Bummer.  Thanks Matheus.