# Is it possible to make a query as a function in Hive

Tags: sql, function, hive

I am thinking about make a query as a function in Hive. For example

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=VALUE
```

I want to make VALUE as an argument of the function. Each time I pass a particular value into it, it can output the query result. I found an example here [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql) ,which is exactly same as what I want to do. But this example is not in Hive.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

What you are looking for is a table-valued function.  Or, in Hive-speak, a UDTF (user-defined table-valued function).

Defining one is not trivial, but it is definitely possible.  The place to start is with the documentation, [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DeveloperGuide+UDTF).