# INSERT INTO ... RETURNING - ambiguous column reference

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

Can someone politely explain this craziness?

```
INSERT INTO "dbo"."UserProfile" ("FirstName")
VALUES('John')
RETURNING "UserProfileId" INTO _UserProfileId;
```

throws an ambiguous reference error, however this correctly executes:

```
INSERT INTO "dbo"."UserProfile" ("FirstName")
VALUES('John')
RETURNING "dbo"."UserProfile"."UserProfileId" INTO _UserProfileId;
```

`_UserProfileId` is a declared integer variable. I couldn't find any references to this syntax in the manual or why on earth this would be ambiguous in any way.

Comment: Is this from a plpgsql function definition? Can you provide some more complete code snippets including the complete function definition as well as the table definition?

Comment: Yes it is. It's a snippet from within a (large) plpgsql function. It's also not just INSERT statements but this error appears in other functions as well seemingly random ways. Is it somehow clashing with column names defined in a RETURNS TABLE() ? I can't narrow down the exact cause.

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce this. You have to provide a minimal complete example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IN` and `OUT` parameters (including columns in `RETURNS TABLE`) are visible inside every SQL command in the body of a plpgsql function.

If you have columns of the same name in your query, you have to table-qualify them to make it unambiguous. In your case, the table name would do:

```
... RETURNING "UserProfile"."UserProfileId" INTO _UserProfileId;
```

[Details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html)

Related:

- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)
- [Naming conflict between function parameter and result of JOIN with USING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/105831/3684)