# <column> is ambiguous in column comparison between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I want this postgres function to work :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION difference_of_match_ids_in_match_history_and_match_results() 
  returns table(match_id BIGINT) 
as 
$$ 
BEGIN   
  return QUERY 
  SELECT * 
  FROM sports.match_history     
  WHERE match_id NOT IN (SELECT match_id 
                         FROM sports.match_results); 
END $$   
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This stand alone query works just fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sports.match_history   
WHERE match_id NOT IN (SELECT match_id FROM sports.match_results);
```

But when I put it into this function and try to run it like this:

```
select * 
from difference_of_match_ids_in_match_history_and_match_results();
```

I get this:

> SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: column reference "match_id" is ambiguous
>   Detail: It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table
>   column.   Where: PL/pgSQL function
>   difference_of_match_ids_in_match_history_and_match_results() line 3 at
>   RETURN QUERY

I've seen other questions with this same error, and they suggest naming the sub queries to specify which instance of a column you're referring to, however, those examples use joins and my query works fine outside of the function.

If I do need to name the column, how would I do so with only one sub-query?

If that isn't the issue, then I'm assuming that there's something wrong with the way I'm defining a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is fine. The ambiguity is on the `match_id` in `returns table(match_id BIGINT)` rename it or prefix the columns with the table name in your query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION difference_of_match_ids_in_match_history_and_match_results() 
  returns table(new_name BIGINT) 
as 
$$ 
BEGIN   
  return QUERY 
  SELECT * 
  FROM sports.match_history     
  WHERE match_id NOT IN (SELECT match_id 
                         FROM sports.match_results); 
END $$   
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION difference_of_match_ids_in_match_history_and_match_results() 
  returns table(match_id BIGINT) 
as 
$$ 
BEGIN   
  return QUERY 
  SELECT sports.match_history.match_id
  FROM sports.match_history     
  WHERE sports.match_history.match_id NOT IN (SELECT sports.match_results.match_id 
                         FROM sports.match_results); 
END $$   
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Didn't test the code.

Comment: Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the result set must match the function result type. If you want to get only `match_ids`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION difference_of_match_ids_in_match_history_and_match_results() 
  RETURNS TABLE(m_id BIGINT)    -- !!
AS 
$$ 
BEGIN   
  RETURN QUERY 
  SELECT match_id               -- !!
  FROM sports.match_history     
  WHERE match_id NOT IN (SELECT match_id 
                         FROM sports.match_results); 
END $$   
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

If you want to get whole rows as a result:

```
DROP FUNCTION difference_of_match_ids_in_match_history_and_match_results();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION difference_of_match_ids_in_match_history_and_match_results() 
  RETURNS SETOF sports.match_history    -- !!
AS
$$ 
BEGIN   
  RETURN QUERY 
  SELECT *                              -- !!
  FROM sports.match_history     
  WHERE match_id NOT IN (SELECT match_id 
                         FROM sports.match_results); 
END $$   
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have answerd, it's an ambiguity between the result definition and PL/pgSQL variables. The column name in a set returning function is in fact also a variable inside the function.

But you don't need PL/pgSQL for this in the first place. If you use a plain SQL function it will be more efficient and the problem will go away as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION difference_of_match_ids_in_match_history_and_match_results() 
  returns table(match_id BIGINT) 
as 
$$ 
  SELECT match_id --<< do not return * - only return one column
  FROM sports.match_history     
  WHERE match_id NOT IN (SELECT match_id 
                         FROM sports.match_results); 
$$   
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Note that the language name is an identifier and should not be quoted at all.

Answer (score 0):

The naming conflict between column names and plpgsql `OUT` parameters has been addressed. More details here:

- [Postgresql - INSERT RETURNING INTO ambiguous column reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261902/postgresql-insert-returning-into-ambiguous-column-reference/39283973#39283973)

I would also use a different query style. `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` is typically slowest and carries traps with NULL values. Use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT match_id
FROM   sports.match_history h 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT match_id 
   FROM   sports.match_results
   WHERE  match_id = h.match_id
   );
```

More:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)