# In plpgsql, return set of composite type without cast?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

This works, but I need the casts (`::name_value_pair`) That seems a bit ugly to me. Is there a way to do it without the casts?

```
create type name_value_pair as (name text, value text);

create or replace function test1()
   returns setof name_value_pair
as $$
begin
    return next ROW('email', 'foo@example.com')::name_value_pair;
    return next ROW('user_id', 'abc123')::name_value_pair;
    return;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Here's the error without the cast. How does it not know it's a `text`? I thought a single quoted string literal was a `text` unless you cast it to something else.

```
psql: ERROR:  returned record type does not match expected record type
DETAIL:  Returned type unknown does not match expected type text in column 1.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test1() line 4 at RETURN NEXT
```

The select:

```
=> select * from test1();
  name   |      value      
---------+-----------------
 email   | foo@example.com
 user_id | abc123
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 12 beta.

Comment: You don't need two queries, one SELECT would be enough. And you don't even need PL/pgSQL for this

Comment: This is not my real application; it's a boiled down example of just the casting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your function is that the ROW constructor "strikes first", creating a composite type of two *unknown* values, for which there is no implicit type conversion.

Here are ***5 ways without using an explicit cast***:

**1.** Still using your predefined composite / row type, with explicit, verbose syntax (educational mostly). The subselect makes the unknown types default to `text` *before* they are composed into a ROW type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1()
  RETURNS SETOF name_value_pair AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN NEXT (SELECT t FROM (SELECT 'email', 'foo@example.com') t);
   RETURN NEXT (SELECT t FROM (SELECT 'user_id', 'abc123') t);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

SELECT * FROM test1();
```

**2.** Using `RETURNS TABLE` and `RETURN QUERY` instead. No need to form composite types to begin with, rather let the function itself do that final step:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2()
  RETURNS TABLE (name text, value text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT 'email', 'foo@example.com';
   RETURN QUERY SELECT 'user_id', 'abc123';
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

SELECT * FROM test2();
```

**3.** Or still use the composite type to define the return type. May be a better fit for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test3()
  RETURNS SETOF name_value_pair AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT 'email', 'foo@example.com';
   RETURN QUERY SELECT 'user_id', 'abc123';
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

SELECT * FROM test3();
```

**4.** While it's that simple, a plain [`VALUES` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) in a plain SQL function is shorter and faster:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test4()
  RETURNS SETOF name_value_pair AS
$func$
VALUES
  ('email', 'foo@example.com')
, ('user_id', 'abc123');
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

SELECT * FROM test4();
```

**5.** Or if it *has* to be PL/pgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test5()
  RETURNS SETOF name_value_pair AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY VALUES
  ('email', 'foo@example.com')
, ('user_id', 'abc123');
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

SELECT * FROM test5();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5f88c1ddb9d342882296a3f0f5c80047)*

The implicit conversion from `unknown` to `text` for scalar return values of a function was added in **Postgres 10**. Postgres 9.6 or older are stricter and would raise a similar error for alternatives 1 - 3. (Only function 4. & 5. work in any Postgres version.)

> ```
> ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
> DETAIL: Returned type unknown does not match expected type text in column 1.
> ```

One might debate whether the still strict behavior for the ROW type was an oversight in that update or by design. A case could be made for either I guess.

Related:

- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)

Comment: I know there is a way to add implicit "casts" to PG. Is there a way to add such a cast from `row(unk, unk)` to `row(text, text)` and/or to the type `name_value_pair`? I don't see a way to refer to `row(unk,unk)` in the `pg_cast` table. Seems like maybe casts only work for *named* types.

Comment: @RobN: Adding to `pg_cast` is not possible as you found out. `unknown` is a [pseudo-type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html) and not allowed in `CREATE TYPE`. So you cannot register a composite type with nested `unknown` fields, hence also no cast based on it. I added three more alternatives above. I think those are better, yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the string constants like 'email' are of type `unknown` not of type `text`.

You could rewrite your example like this:

```sql
create type name_value_pair as (name text, value text);

create or replace function test1()
   returns setof name_value_pair
as $$
begin
    return next ROW('email'::text, 'foo@example.com'::text);
    return next ROW('user_id'::text, 'abc123'::text);
    return;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: If a string literal is of type `unknown`, then why does it work if I change it to return `setof text` and say `return next 'email'`? That doesn't need a cast.

Comment: Apparently in this case postgres is able to do an implicit type conversion. Here in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/typeconv-overview.html), right after the first example you can find a statment about `unknown` for string literals and how to guide the parser.