# Postgresql trying to use execute format in a function but getting column not found error when giving string format in coalesce

Tags: sql, postgresql, format, execute

I'm trying to create a function and specify a date format but the date format is being taken as a column name because somehow inside format it's not being able to be represented as a string. I have tried %s, quote indent and everything else but doesnt work. Below is my code and the error I'm getting

```
drop function if exists foo(_t text);
create or replace function foo(_t text)
returns TABLE(Stage_ID bigint,Date varchar) as
$func$
begin
    return query

        execute format('Select Stage_ID,Date
        from table
        where to_date(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD")==%I',_t);
end
$func$  language plpgsql;
```

```
select * from foo('2010-01-01');
```

**ERROR**

```
ERROR:  column "YYYY-MM-DD" does not exist
LINE:         where TO_DATE(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") =  p...
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you are looking for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_t text)
  RETURNS TABLE (Stage_ID bigint, Date varchar) AS
$func$
   SELECT t.Stage_ID, t.Date
   FROM   tbl t
   WHERE  t.Date = _t::date;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

- The expression `where to_date(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD")==%I',_t);` is backwards in multiple ways.

  - Single quotes for *values*: `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.
  - The operator is `=`, not `==`.
  - Seems like you really want `t.Date = to_date(_t, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`
  - And while `_t` is in standard ISO form 'YYYY-MM-DD', rather just cast instead: `t.Date = _t::date`.
- Output column names are visible inside the function body. Table-qualify column of the same name. Better yet, avoid naming conflicts like that to begin with! See:

  - [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)
- No need for dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`. Passing a data value works just fin with plain SQL.
- No need for plpgsql. The simple query does not require any procedural functionality. `LANGUAGE sql` does the job - if you need a function at all, plain SQL would seem just fine for the job.

Aside: don't use basic type names like "date" as identifier. Stick to legal, lower case identifiers. Related:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution.Also, sorry for not posting this exact code but there's another parameter 'schema' which specifies the schema name to select the table from the correct schema ```foo(schem text, _t text)``` which doesn't work in the standard sql format as you've shown. And sorry for those == and single quote errors, didn't write it properly.

Comment: ```execute format('Select Stage_ID,Date
        from schem.table
        where to_date(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD")==%I',_t);```

Comment: So do you have your answer?