# How do I return a single column in psotgres function?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, stored-functions

So, I have this schema:

```
node_mapping(node_id: UUID, node_name: text, related_ids: jsonb)
```

I wanted to write a postgres function for this query so that I get a List as the output in my JPA method in Springboot.

```
select CAST(node_id AS VARCHAR) node_id from node_mapping where related_ids::jsonb? _seller_id = true;
```

I wrote this function but it isn't working, please help me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_node_id(_relation_id text)
 RETURNS TABLE(node_id text) AS
 $func$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY select CAST(node_id AS VARCHAR) node_id from node_mapping where related_ids::jsonb? _relation_id = true;
    END;
 $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Please help me, what m I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please remember to disclose the verbatim error message you got for your next question. And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what's "not working", but I see an **ambiguous column reference "node_id"**. Easily fixed by table-qualifying the column name:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_node_id(_relation_id text)
  RETURNS TABLE(node_id text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT n.node_id::text    -- HERE!
   FROM   node_mapping n
   WHERE  n.related_ids ? _relation_id;
END
$func$;
```

Note that `node_id` in the `RETURNS TABLE` declaration is implicitly visible as `OUT` parameter in the whole function body. So you need to disambiguate between it and the column with the same name.

Related:

- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)

I fixed a couple of other oddities (that would still work, though). Among other things, you don't need to cast `related_ids::jsonb` when the column is already type `jsonb`.

A final `RETURN;` is optional. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4)

> A final `RETURN`, which should have no argument, causes control to exit the function (or you can just let control reach the end of the function).

For the simple example, rather use a simpler, equivalent **SQL function**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_node_id(_relation_id text)
  RETURNS TABLE(node_id text)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT n.node_id::text
FROM   node_mapping n
WHERE  n.related_ids ? _relation_id;
$func$;
```

Or, equivalent:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_node_id(_relation_id text, OUT node_id text)
  RETURNS SETOF record
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT n.node_id::text
FROM   node_mapping n
WHERE  n.related_ids ? _relation_id;
$func$;
```