# Return an Array Column from a PostgreSQL Stored Function

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a function that returns a query based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945958/4808122)

It works fine except for the columns that are of type `array` - result of `array_agg` on *tuples*

**Simplified Example**

Note that in the real case the arrays result from a `group by` subquery.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_array()
  RETURNS TABLE (o_id   int 
               , o_arr text[]
               )
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   with dt as
    (select 'x' col1, 'y' col2)
   select 1 id, 
       (select array_agg((col1,col2)) from dt) arr; 
END
$func$;

SELECT * FROM get_array();
```

*Error*

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
  Detail: Returned type record[] does not match expected type text[] in column 2.
  Where: SQL statement "with dt as

    (select 'x' col1, 'y' col2)

   select 1 id, 

       (select array_agg((col1,col2)) from dt) arr"
PL/pgSQL function get_array() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

How should I define the *array* column in the returning table type?

The query returns following data

```
with dt as
(select 'x' col1, 'y' col2)
select 1 id, 
       (select array_agg((col1,col2)) from dt) arr;

|id |arr      |
|---|---------|
|1  |{"(x,y)"}|
```

Comment: Why PL/pgSQL here? A `language sql` function would be more efficient

Comment: Well I simple copy the code from the example I linked @a_horse_with_no_name. Not sure why, but if I only change the language to `sql` leaving all other unchnaged I receive `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURN"`

Comment: Well, `array_agg((col1,col2))` produces an array of records (`record[]`)  not array text (`text[]`)

Comment: Yes, there is probable too much nesting, if I define the type `record[]` instead of `text[]` compilation fails with `PL/pgSQL functions cannot accept type record[]`. Is there a chance with this approach or do I need to split in two simple arrays? @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

Array function used to convert your value into array
Array agg function used to group of tyo particular column value aggregate value of group by your particular column

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_array()
  RETURNS TABLE (o_id   int 
               , o_arr text[]
               )
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   with dt as
    (select 'x' col1, 'y' col2)
   select 1 id, 
   (array_agg(array(col1,col2)))::text[] from DT group by 1
END
$func$;
```

Comment: This works, but it returns an array of *strings* `"(x,y)"` not an array of arrays.

Comment: with dt as
    (select 'x' col1, 'y' col2)
   select 1 id, 
   (array_agg(array(col1,col2)))::text[] from DT group by 1 used this query in your function