# What's the correct typecast for a variable inside this query?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I was writing this cypher query as a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.count_friends(name agtype) 
    RETURNS agtype AS $function$
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
        MATCH (v:Person)-[]-(w)
        WHERE v.name = name
        RETURN COUNT(w) AS friends
    $$) AS (friends agtype);
    END;
$function$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I was using this select query for testing:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
        MATCH (v:Person)
      WHERE public.count_friends(v.name) > 3
      RETURN v.name
$$) AS (name agtype);
```

But, I got an error while executing it:

```
ERROR:  could not find rte for name
LINE 3:         WHERE v.name = name
```

What's the correct typecast for the variable name in this case? Or, is there something wrong with my code?

Environment: Apache AGE 1.3.0 release, PostgreSQL 13.10, Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I'll try to replicate your query here, but which file and what additional changes you made (if any) to create this function?

Comment: Hi Matheus! I didn't make any modifications in the code, so you might be able to replicate this by just using the same query

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with `public.count_friends(name agtype)` function.
Study this answer to get understand how to return the result from a query inside PostgreSQL function:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945958/20972645

Also, the comparison of variables taken as arguments of function with any variable declared or taken by any query within that function gives type miss match errors. Like:

```
DETAIL:  Expected agtype value
```

For now, you need to find a way around to achieve this functionality.

Comment: I manage to run this function using `RETURN QUERY`

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting might be because the number that is compared in the `WHERE` clause for the testing might be higher than the number of available vertices (`WHERE public.count_friends(v.name) > 3`).

First, I created a graph to store the `Person` vertices with the `name` property.

```sql
demo=# SELECT create_graph('graph_name');
NOTICE:  graph "graph_name" has been created
 create_graph 
--------------
 
(1 row)

demo=# SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
CREATE (a:Person {name: 'Wendel'}), (b:Person {name: 'Matheus'})
RETURN a, b
$$) AS (a agtype, b agtype);
                                          a                                           |                                           b                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Person", "properties": {"name": "Wendel"}}::vertex | {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Person", "properties": {"name": "Matheus"}}::vertex
(1 row)
```

After this, created the function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.count_friends(name agtype) 
    RETURNS agtype AS $function$
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
        MATCH (v:Person)-[]-(w)
        WHERE v.name = name
        RETURN COUNT(w) AS friends
    $$) AS (friends agtype);
    END;
$function$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then executed the test query without the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
demo=# SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
      MATCH (v:Person)
      RETURN v.name                    
$$) AS (name agtype);

   name    
-----------
 "Wendel"
 "Matheus"
(2 rows)
```

It worked fine this way.

Comment: I actually need to call the public.count_friends function, which is why I included the `WHERE` clause there

Comment: Oh yeah my bad! lol I'm going nuts here, I'll try to find the answer again and edit the answer if I get any results.

Comment: That's okay! Hahah I'll be waiting for the response, I think I got the type of the variable `name` wrong