# PL/pgSQL: Delete (update) row matching a record

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, record, plpgsql, sql-delete

I'm writing three triggers in PL/pgSQL. In each case, I have a `RECORD` variable and want to insert that into a table, delete it from the table, or update it to represent a second `RECORD` variable.

Adding is easy: `INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (NEW.*);`

Deleting isn't as easy, there doesn't seem to be a syntax for something like this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE * = OLD.*;
```

Updating has the same problem. Is there an easy solution, short of generating matching SQL queries that compare each attribute using ideas from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13079081/926412)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trick for delete

```
create table t(a int, b int);
create table ta(a int, b int);

create function t1_delete() 
returns trigger as $$
begin 
  delete from ta where ta = old; 
  return null; 
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

But this trick doesn't work for UPDATE. So fully simple trigger in PL/pgSQL is not possible simply.

Comment: Cool - didn't know that. By replacing UPDATE with DELETE + INSERT (which might not work correctly if there are triggers on that table), one could expand that to a fully working generic solution (except for the trigger problem). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You write about a record variable and it is, indeed, not trivial to [access individual columns of an **anonymous record** in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159768/passing-column-names-dynamically-for-a-record-variable-in-postgresql/18162632#18162632).

**However**, in your example, you only use `OLD` and `NEW`, which are **well known row types**, defined by the underlying table. It is trivial to access individual columns in this case.

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE mytable_id = OLD.mytable_id;

UPDATE mytable_b
SET    some_col = NEW.some_other_col
WHERE  some_id  = NEW.mytable_id;
```

Etc.

Just be careful not to create endless loops.

In case you just want to "update" columns of the *current* row, you can simply assign to columns the `NEW` object in the trigger. You know that, right?

```
NEW.some_col := 'foo';
```

#### Dynamic column names

If you don't know column names beforehand, you can still do this generically with dynamic SQL as detailed in this related answer:
[Update multiple columns in a trigger function in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343075/update-multiple-columns-in-a-trigger-function-in-plpgsql/15351196#15351196)

Comment: My problem with this approach is that I need to (manually) customize my trigger for each table to include the column names - I ended up writing a script to automatically generate these triggers for me.

Comment: @fefrei: I added a paragraph for *dynamic* column names.