# PLpgSQL function to find columns with only NULL values in a given table

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-functions, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

We have to find columns of a table with only NULL values. We are trying to build a plpgsql function that takes a table's name and returns the list of such columns.

How to create such a function?

We are using PgAdmin 1.16.

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite your question to better reflect your actual problem according to your comments.

Comment: BTW, pgAdmin is just a GUI and has no influence on this question. [But I suggest you upgrade to the current version 1.18.1.](http://pgadmin.org/download/)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2714/finding-empty-columns-of-a-table-in-postgresql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the catalog table [`pg_attribute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-attribute.html) to get a list of columns which are not defined `NOT NULL` and therefore *can* hold `NULL` values:

```
SELECT quote_ident(attname) AS column_can_be_null
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'tbl'::regclass -- valid, visible table name 
AND    attnum >= 1                -- exclude tableoid & friends
AND    NOT attisdropped           -- exclude dropped columns
AND    NOT attnotnull             -- exclude columns defined NOT NULL!
ORDER  BY attnum;
```

Where `tbl` is your (optionally schema-qualified) table name.

Doesn't say there are any actual NULL values in the column. You'd have to test each column. Like this:

#### Full automation with plpgsql function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_all_null_columns_of_tbl(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS SETOF text AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _row_ct  bigint;        -- count rows in table $1
   _sql     text;          -- SQL string to test for NULL values
   _cols    text[];        -- array of candidate column names
   _nulls   bool[];        -- array of test results
BEGIN

EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || _tbl
INTO _row_ct;

IF _row_ct = 0 THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Table % has no rows!', _tbl;  -- pointless for empty table
ELSE
   RAISE NOTICE '% rows in table %.', _row_ct, _tbl; 
END IF;

SELECT INTO _sql, _cols
      'SELECT ARRAY[' || string_agg('bool_and(' || col || ' IS NULL)', ', ')
       || '] FROM ' || _tbl
    , array_agg(col)
FROM  (
   SELECT quote_ident(attname) AS col
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _tbl            -- valid, visible table name 
   AND    attnum >= 1                -- exclude tableoid & friends
   AND    NOT attisdropped           -- exclude dropped columns
   AND    NOT attnotnull             -- exclude columns defined NOT NULL!
   ORDER  BY attnum
   ) sub;

EXECUTE _sql INTO _nulls;

FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(_cols, 1)
LOOP
   IF _nulls[i] THEN                 -- column is NULL in all rows
      RETURN NEXT _cols[i];
   END IF;
END LOOP;

RETURN;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_all_null_columns_of_tbl('my_schema.my_table');
```

Tested with Postgres 9.1 and 9.3.
This uses a number of advanced plpgsql features.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ec8ed/1)

Related answer building SQL code and executing it, with modern syntax:

- [Replace empty strings with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621897/replace-blank-spaces-with-null-values/10686513#10686513)

About traversing a record:

- [Loop through columns of RECORD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065774/pl-pgsql-loop-through-columns-of-record/13079081#13079081)

Comment: Dear Erwin Brandstetter, Thx for your kindly idea 
i need null value columns(empty columns all the values are null)
 i tried your Query. it worked, but those results are showing some data tables also. Eg: i tried country table, there domain_name column has null values, but this query shows 6 table names i need function type query. Thanks Erwin Brandstetter for your wonderful query

Comment: @Pathman: Ah, I think I get it now. You should edit your question with this clarification. Use "edit" left under your question.

Comment: @ Erwin Brandstetter :I edit your query to function type

Comment: @ Erwin Brandstetter: It is very usefully function,i solved some other function based on this function. I'm very happy now. Thx Erwin Brandstetter