# PostgreSQL modifying fields dynamically in NEW record in a trigger function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a user table with IDs and usernames (and other details) and several other tables referring to this table with various column names (`CONSTRAINT some_name FOREIGN KEY (columnname) REFERENCES "user" (userid)`). What I need to do is add the usernames to the referring tables (in preparation for dropping the whole user table). This is of course easily accomplished with a single `ALTER TABLE` and `UPDATE`, and keeping these up-to-date with triggers is also (fairly) easy. But it's the trigger function that is causing me some annoyance. I could have used individual functions for each table, but this seemed redundant, so I created one common function for this purpose:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add_username() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    sourcefield text;
    targetfield text;
    username text;
    existing text;
  BEGIN
    IF (TG_NARGS != 2) THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Need source field and target field parameters';
    END IF;
    sourcefield = TG_ARGV[0];
    targetfield = TG_ARGV[1];
    EXECUTE 'SELECT username FROM "user" WHERE userid = ($1).' || sourcefield INTO username USING NEW;
    EXECUTE format('SELECT ($1).%I', targetfield) INTO existing USING NEW;
    IF ((TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND existing IS NULL) OR (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND (existing IS NULL OR username != existing))) THEN
      CASE targetfield
        WHEN 'username' THEN
          NEW.username := username;
        WHEN 'modifiername' THEN
          NEW.modifiername := username;
        WHEN 'creatorname' THEN
          NEW.creatorname := username;
        .....
      END CASE;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

And using the trigger function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER some_trigger_name BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON my_schema.my_table FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.add_username('userid', 'username');
```

The way this works is the trigger function receives the original source field name (for example `userid`) and the target field name (`username`) via TG_ARGV. These are then used to fill in the (possibly) missing information. All this works nice enough, but how can I get rid of that `CASE`-mess? Is there a way to dynamically modify the values in the `NEW` record when I don't know the name of the field in advance (or rather it can be a lot of things)? It is in the `targetfield` parameter, but obviously `NEW.targetfield` does not work, nor something like `NEW[targetfield]` (like Javascript for example).

Any ideas how this could be accomplished? Besides using for instance PL/Python..

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711432/how-to-set-value-of-composite-variable-field-using-dynamic-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not simple plpgsql based solutions. Some possible solutions:

1. Using [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/hstore.html) extension.

```
CREATE TYPE footype AS (a int, b int, c int);

postgres=# select row(10,20,30);
    row     
------------
 (10,20,30)
(1 row)

postgres=# select row(10,20,30)::footype #= 'b=>100';
  ?column?   
-------------
 (10,100,30)
(1 row)
```

`hstore` based function can be very simple:

```
create or replace function update_fields(r anyelement,
                                         variadic changes text[])
returns anyelement as $$
select $1 #= hstore($2);
$$ language sql;

postgres=# select * 
             from update_fields(row(10,20,30)::footype, 
                                'b', '1000', 'c', '800');
 a  |  b   |  c  
----+------+-----
 10 | 1000 | 800
(1 row)
```

2. Some years ago I wrote a extension [pl toolbox](http://postgres.cz/wiki/PL_toolbox_%28en%29). There is a function `record_set_fields`:

```
pavel=# select * from pst.record_expand(pst.record_set_fields(row(10,20),'f1',33));
 name | value |   typ   
------+-------+---------
 f1   | 33    | integer
 f2   | 20    | integer
(2 rows)
```

Probably you can find some plpgsql only solutions based on some tricks with system tables and arrays like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065774/pl-pgsql-loop-through-columns-of-record/13078982#13078982), but I cannot to suggest it. It is too less readable and for not advanced user just only black magic. `hstore` is simple and almost everywhere so it should be preferred way.

On PostgreSQL 9.4 (maybe 9.3) you can try to black magic with JSON manipulations:

```
postgres=# select json_populate_record(NULL::footype, jo) 
              from (select json_object(array_agg(key),
                                       array_agg(case key when 'b' 
                                                          then 1000::text
                                                          else value 
                                                 end)) jo
       from json_each_text(row_to_json(row(10,20,30)::footype))) x;
 json_populate_record 
----------------------
 (10,1000,30)
(1 row)
```

So I am able to write function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_field(r anyelement, 
                                               fn text, val text, 
                                               OUT result anyelement)
 RETURNS anyelement
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare jo json;
begin
  jo := (select json_object(array_agg(key), 
                            array_agg(case key when 'b' then val
                                               else value end)) 
            from json_each_text(row_to_json(r)));
  result := json_populate_record(r, jo);
end;
$function$

postgres=# select * from update_field(row(10,20,30)::footype, 'b', '1000');
 a  |  b   | c  
----+------+----
 10 | 1000 | 30
(1 row)
```

JSON based function should not be terrible fast. `hstore` should be faster.

Comment: I thought about trying JSON too, but you're right, it is probably not all that fast, and `hstore` was my second choice as well but I figured I'd ask for a "pure" solution first. Seems that I have no choice but to go with that then. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is a hard coding in the json-based update_field function. For "case key when 'b' then",  where 'b' should be replaced with fn. I was not able to improve your answer directly  (2000 points are required for making changes less than 6 chars)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE/caution:** Erwin points out that this is currently undocumented,  and the docs indicates it should not be possible to alter records this way.
Use [Pavel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28284491/1914376) or hstore.

The json based solution is almost as fast as hstore when simplified. json_populate_record() modifies existing records for us, so we only have to create a json object from the keys we want to change.

See my [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28673097/1914376), where you'll find benchmarks that compares the solutions.

The simplest solution requires Postgres **9.4**:

```
SELECT json_populate_record (
      record
     ,json_build_object('key', 'new-value')
);
```

But if you only have Postgres **9.3**, you can use casting instead of json_object:

```
SELECT json_populate_record( 
     record
    , ('{"'||'key'||'":"'||'new-value'||'"}')::json
);
```

Comment: This feature is currently undocumented. Even worse: [the manual is indicates otherwise](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html): `and target columns that do not match any JSON field will simply be NULL`. Pavel posted something related to this on pgsql-hackers: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/30106.1424989904@sss.pgh.pa.us#30106.1424989904@sss.pgh.pa.us