# Passing column names dynamically for a record variable in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, types, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, hstore

Using PostgreSQL, column values from a table for 1st record are stored in a record variable. for ex: let the variable be: `recordvar`

```
recordvar.columnname
```

gives the value of the column name specified. I will define the `columname` in a variable:

```
var := columnname
```

In place of `columnname` if I replace with the variable i.e. `recordvar.var`, it is not working.

Please let me know how to proceed in this situation. Following is the sample code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getrowdata(id numeric, table_name character varying)
RETURNS SETOF void AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE

srowdata record;
reqfield character varying;
value numeric;


BEGIN

RAISE NOTICE 'id: %',id; 
reqfield:= 'columnname';

EXECUTE 'select * from datas.'||table_name||' WHERE id = '||id into srowdata;

RAISE NOTICE 'srowdata: %',srowdata; 

RAISE NOTICE 'srowdatadata.columnname: %',srowdata.columnname;

value:= srowdata.reqfield;

RAISE NOTICE 'value: %',value;


END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
```

Answer (score 24):

Working with this dummy table

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo (id int, my_num numeric);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 12.34)
```

First, I simplified and sanitized your example:

- Removed some noise that is irrelevant to the question.
- `RETURNS SETOF void` hardly makes sense. I use `RETURNS void` instead.
- I use `text` instead of `character varying`, just for the sake of simplicity.
- When using dynamic SQL, you *have* to safeguard against SQL injection, I use `format()` with `%I` in this case. [There are other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349).

The basic problem is that SQL is very rigid with types and identifiers. You are operating with *dynamic table* name as well as with *dynamic field name of a record* - an ***anonymous* record** in your original example. Pl/pgSQL is not well equipped to deal with this. Postgres does not know what's *inside* an anonymous record. Only after you assign the record to a *well known type* can you reference individual fields.
Here is a closely related question, trying to *set* a field of a record with dynamic name:
[How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711432/how-to-set-value-of-composite-variable-field-using-dynamic-sql)

### Basic function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getrowdata1(table_name text, id int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$ 
DECLARE
   srowdata record;
   reqfield text := 'my_num';   -- assigning at declaration time for convenience
   value    numeric;
BEGIN

RAISE NOTICE 'id: %', id; 

EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I WHERE id = $1', table_name)
USING  id
INTO   srowdata;

RAISE NOTICE 'srowdata: %', srowdata;

RAISE NOTICE 'srowdatadata.my_num: %', srowdata.my_num;

/* This does not work, even with dynamic SQL
EXECUTE format('SELECT ($1).%I', reqfield)
USING srowdata
INTO value;

RAISE NOTICE 'value: %', value;
*/

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * from getrowdata1('foo', 1);
```

The commented part would raise an exception:

> could not identify column "my_num" in record data type: SELECT * from
>   getrowdata(1,'foo')

### `hstore`

You need to install the additional module [**hstore**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html) for this. Once per database with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

Then all could work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getrowdata2(table_name text, id int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$ 
DECLARE
   hstoredata hstore;
   reqfield   text := 'my_num';
   value      numeric;
BEGIN

RAISE NOTICE 'id: %', id; 

EXECUTE format('SELECT hstore(t) FROM %I t WHERE id = $1', table_name)
USING  id
INTO   hstoredata;

RAISE NOTICE 'hstoredata: %', hstoredata;

RAISE NOTICE 'hstoredata.my_num: %', hstoredata -> 'my_num';

value := hstoredata -> reqfield;

RAISE NOTICE 'value: %', value;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * from getrowdata2('foo', 1);
```

### Polymorphic type

Alternative without installing additional modules.

Since you select a whole row into your record variable, there is a **well defined type** for it per definition. Use it. The key word is [**polymorphic types**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getrowdata3(_tbl anyelement, id int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$ 
DECLARE
   reqfield text := 'my_num';
   value    numeric;
BEGIN

RAISE NOTICE 'id: %', id; 

EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = $1', pg_typeof(_tbl))
USING  id
INTO   _tbl;

RAISE NOTICE '_tbl: %', _tbl;

RAISE NOTICE '_tbl.my_num: %', _tbl.my_num;

EXECUTE 'SELECT ($1).' || reqfield   -- requfield must be SQLi-safe or escape
USING _tbl
INTO  value;

RAISE NOTICE 'value: %', value;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * from getrowdata3(NULL::foo, 1);
```

[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/71f23/1)

- I (ab-)use the input parameter `_tbl` for *three* purposes here:

  - Provides the well defined **type** of the record
  - Provides the **name** of the table, automatically schema-qualified
  - Serves as variable.
- More explanation in this related answer (last chapter):
  [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: Hi i am gettin Error:record "_tbl" has no field "my_num", could you help please

Comment: @ismail: You need to be a lot more specific, and start a new *question*, please. Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for reference.