# How to declare a variable using exact structure of the refcursor?

Tags: postgresql, loops, cursor, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

My database is PostgreSQL 9.3.5.

I have a dynamic query which will be populated with a different number of columns for each run. For that we have to capture that runtime structure. we thought `refcursor` structure is okay. But how to declare?

Example:

```
DECLARE
  curs1 refcursor;
  v_cols  curs1%ROWTYPE;----> It is giving us error
BEGIN
  OPEN curs1 FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM '|| tablename||'';
  LOOP
    FETCH curs1 INTO ....;  --->Here how to capture the data
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE curs1;
END;
```

Comment: yes,exactly thanks a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Always include the function header in questions, it's an integral part of the function. Parameters and return type are relevant for the rest to make sense. The data type of  `tablename` for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Like @a_horse commented, [**`record`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS) will do the job. Be aware that `record` is just a placeholder for any row type and cannot be accessed before it is assigned to the first time:

- [Passing column names dynamically for a record variable in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159768/passing-column-names-dynamically-for-a-record-variable-in-postgresql/18162632#18162632)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS ??? AS
$func$
DECLARE
  v_cols record;
BEGIN
  FOR v_cols IN
     EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM '|| _tbl;
  LOOP
     -- loop is only entered if a (next) row is found
     -- do stuff
  END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

A [**`FOR` loop**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) is typically simpler and faster than handling cursors manually.

- [Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database/12082038#12082038)
- [Cursor based records in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339628/cursor-based-records-in-postgresql/22340544#22340544)

For dynamic code use **`FOR-IN-EXECUTE`** - and be sure to defend against SQL injection!
**`regclass`** as data type for the parameter does that for (existing!) tablenames:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)