# How to get a result from dynamic SQL in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

Raw Table for which rule are stored in one table named md_formula , which are used to map in destination table

**Drop/Create/Insert for `raw_dbs_transactiondetailscash`**:

```
DROP TABLE raw_dbs_transactiondetailscash

CREATE TABLE raw_dbs_transactiondetailscash(
    accountnumber VARCHAR(100),
    referencecurrency VARCHAR(100),
    transactiondate datetime)

INSERT INTO raw_dbs_transactiondetailscash(
    accountnumber, referencecurrency, transactiondate)
    SELECT 'XYZ','$','01/01/2016'
```

**Drop/Create/Insert  for `md_formula`**:

```
DROP TABLE MD_Formula 

CREATE TABLE MD_Formula (
    Format VARCHAR(20),
    tbl_Src VARCHAR(200),
    Col_src VARCHAR(500),
    tbl_Des VARCHAR(200),
    Col_des VARCHAR(100),
    Condition VARCHAR(500) )

INSERT INTO md_formula(format, tbl_src, Col_src, tbl_des,Col_des)    
    SELECT 'Dbs','raw_dbs_transactiondetailscash','accountnumber',
            'normalized_transaction','account_number'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Dbs','raw_dbs_transactiondetailscash','referencecurrency',
            'normalized_transaction','currency'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Dbs','raw_dbs_transactiondetailscash','transactiondate',
            'normalized_transaction','trade_date'
```

Get the data from  raw table stored in md_Formula
Via `TSQL` (Only One Column Selected for Example)

This will actually execute

```
SELECT accountnumber
FROM raw_dbs_transactiondetailscash
```

and get set of data from `raw_dbs_transactiondetailscash` table

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(100)

SELECT TOP 1 @sql= 'SELECT '+Col_src+ ' FROM '+tbl_Src FROM MD_Formula

EXEC (@sql)
```

Via `Postgres` (Dynamic Query is prepared only, how to get data from  raw table in dynamic sql is still a question)

This need to execute

```
SELECT accountnumber,referencecurrency,transactiondate
FROM raw_dbs_transactiondetailscash
```

and get result

```
SELECT 'SELECT '|| string_Agg(col_src,',') ||' FROM ' ||  tbl_src FROM md_formula
WHERE format='Dbs'
GROUP BY tbl_src
```

Comment: Please post your table definition as formatted text, not links to screenshots. You also need to add the expected output of the query, I for one have no idea what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a dynamic query you need to use the `execute` command.

```
EXECUTE dynamic-query-string INTO target-variable...
```

The manual page for this is here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

HTH

Comment: The Dynamic Query  prepared by the above query is a result with set of rows which i feel can not be assigned to variable.

Comment: @HarsimranjeetSingh that can be assigned too, you could use multiple variables, `record` or a row-typed variable to do that (in case of fix number of columns). The only part, which can be hard is [reading from a general `record` type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159768/passing-column-names-dynamically-for-a-record-variable-in-postgresql). But you can use [`json`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) or [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) for a more general solution (in case of varying column numbers / types).

Comment: @pozs below is the query so far accomplised but this is throwing error .I want to return record type variable at the EOD.                                                                                         CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getrowdata1()
RETURNS setof record AS
$func$
DECLARE
srowdata record;
sql VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
/*sql:=(SELECT 'SELECT '|| string_Agg(col_src,',') ||' FROM ' ||  tbl_src FROM md_formula
WHERE format='Dbs'
GROUP BY tbl_src);*/
sql:= (SELECT 'SELECT * FROM md_formula');
EXECUTE(sql)
INTO srowdata;
RETURN srowdata;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: @HarsimranjeetSingh you cannot use return if your function is defined as returning a 'setof'.  As you only want to return a single result, remove the 'setof' keyword from the function definition.

Comment: I've tried the same and when used
SELECT getrowdata1() the result is coming as a weird text . like ("MDXCDSD1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       (...)

Comment: How do you mean 'weird text' ?  Does it contain the values you'd expect to see in a strange format or just gibberish?

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i've  tried to attained result as per my requirement.
Thanks to @pozs your link to some post was really helpful, Appreciated.

Solution:

```
Create or replace Function gen_Test(query_name refcursor)
returns refcursor
as $$
Declare sql text;
begin
sql:=(SELECT 'SELECT '|| string_Agg(col_src,',') ||' FROM ' ||  tbl_src FROM md_formula
WHERE format='Dbs'
GROUP BY tbl_src);
open query_name for execute 
sql;
return query_name;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;


select gen_Test('english');
fetch all in english;
```

PS: Appreciated everyone feedback for giving time for this issue.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to insert from this into table. posted same question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172019/insert-from-dynamic-query-in-postgres)