# PostgreSQL: Remove attribute from JSON column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-json

I need to remove some attributes from a json type column.

The Table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table( id VARCHAR(80), data json);
INSERT INTO my_table (id, data) VALUES (
  'A', 
  '{"attrA":1,"attrB":true,"attrC":["a", "b", "c"]}'
);
```

Now, I need to remove `attrB` from column `data`.

Something like `alter table my_table drop column data->'attrB';` would be nice. But a way with a temporary table would be enough, too.

Comment: What is your postgres version?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

**Update**: for 9.5+, there are explicit operators you can use with `jsonb` (if you have a `json` typed column, you can use casts to apply a modification):

Deleting a key (or an index) from a JSON object (or, from an array) can be done with the `-` operator:

```
SELECT jsonb '{"a":1,"b":2}' - 'a', -- will yield jsonb '{"b":2}'
       jsonb '["a",1,"b",2]' - 1    -- will yield jsonb '["a","b",2]'
```

Deleting, from deep in a JSON hierarchy can be done with the `#-` operator:

```
SELECT '{"a":[null,{"b":[3.14]}]}' #- '{a,1,b,0}'
-- will yield jsonb '{"a":[null,{"b":[]}]}'
```

For 9.4, you can use a modified version of the original answer (below), but instead of aggregating a JSON string, you can aggregate into a `json` object directly with `json_object_agg()`.

Related: other JSON manipulations whithin PostgreSQL:

- [How do I modify fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23500670/1499698)

**Original answer** (applies to PostgreSQL 9.3):

If you have at least PostgreSQL 9.3, you can split your object into pairs with `json_each()` and filter your unwanted fields, then build up the json again manually. Something like:

```
SELECT data::text::json AS before,
       ('{' || array_to_string(array_agg(to_json(l.key) || ':' || l.value), ',') || '}')::json AS after
FROM (VALUES ('{"attrA":1,"attrB":true,"attrC":["a","b","c"]}'::json)) AS v(data),
LATERAL (SELECT * FROM json_each(data) WHERE "key" <> 'attrB') AS l
GROUP BY data::text
```

With 9.2 (or lower) it is not possible.

**Edit**:

A more convenient form is to create a function, which can remove any number of attributes in a `json` field:

**Edit 2**: `string_agg()` is less expensive than `array_to_string(array_agg())`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "json_object_delete_keys"("json" json, VARIADIC "keys_to_delete" TEXT[])
  RETURNS json
  LANGUAGE sql
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
AS $function$
SELECT COALESCE(
  (SELECT ('{' || string_agg(to_json("key") || ':' || "value", ',') || '}')
   FROM json_each("json")
   WHERE "key" <> ALL ("keys_to_delete")),
  '{}'
)::json
$function$;
```

With this function, all you need to do is to run the query below:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET data = json_object_delete_keys(data, 'attrB');
```

Comment: @RezaS not directly this, but you can combine the recursive variant (in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23500670/1499698 ) with this (see my comment there).

Comment: Do you need the `, {}` in the query? I think you can leave that out too

Comment: @RezaS without that, the function would return null when you empty an object of all its keys, I think.

Comment: @voxobscuro yes, exactly. however in new "versions", I used to write `concat('{', ..., '}')`, because `concat` will ignore nulls.

Comment: I am trying to pass two values and it is not working and not giving any errors:
UPDATE my_table
SET data = json_object_delete_keys(data, '{"attrB", "attrC"}');

Comment: @Za7pi the function in the answer is [`VARIADIC`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) -- you should call it like `json_object_delete_keys(data, 'attrB', 'attrC')` or `json_object_delete_keys(data, VARIADIC '{"attrB", "attrC"}'::text[])`

Comment: instead of manually build json with string_agg/array_agg we can build it with json_agg("key","value")

Comment: * json_object_agg

Comment: @AlexanderHasselbach this answer was created for 9.3 a long ago, when there were no `json_object_agg()`. Now there is an explicit operator for OP's problem (so there is no need to use that function either), I'll update my answer soon.

Answer (score 76):

This has gotten much easier with PostgreSQL 9.5 using the JSONB type.  See JSONB operators documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).

You can remove a top-level attribute with the "-" operator.

```
SELECT '{"a": {"key":"value"}, "b": 2, "c": true}'::jsonb - 'a'
// -> {"b": 2, "c": true}
```

You can use this within an update call to update an existing JSONB field.

```
UPDATE my_table SET data = data - 'attrB'
```

You can also provide the attribute name dynamically via parameter if used in a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_mytable_data_key(
    _id integer,
    _key character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE my_table SET
        data = data - _key
    WHERE id = _id;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

The reverse operator is the "||", in order to concatenate two JSONB packets together.  Note that the right-most use of the attribute will overwrite any previous ones.

```
SELECT '{"a": true, "c": true}'::jsonb || '{"a": false, "b": 2}'::jsonb 
// -> {"a": false, "b": 2, "c": true}
```

Answer (score 41):

I was facing similar issue to remove a key-value pair from an existing json column in postgres. I was able to fix this using `-` operator as follows:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET data = data::jsonb - 'attrB'
WHERE id = 'A';
```

Comment: I dunno why there's no one up vote u. Your solution is very simple and works, great. Thank u so much.

Comment: This is the best solution: works not only with `json` data type but also with `text`.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to remove a sub-field, like:

```json
{
  "a": {
    "b": "REMOVE ME!"
  }
}
```

You can simply use:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET my_json_column = my_json_column::jsonb #- '{a,b}';
```

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't get `SELECT '{"a": "b"}'::jsonb - 'a';` to work in 9.5.2.  However, `SELECT '{"a": "b"}'::jsonb #- '{a}';` did work!

Answer (score 6):

Simply use the `#-` operator, for example:

```
SELECT '{"foo": 10, "bar": [], "baz": {}}'::jsonb #- '{baz}';
```

Comment: for a top-level key, you can just use `-`. It would go like this `SELECT '{"foo": 10, "bar": [], "baz": {}}'::jsonb - 'baz';` (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html for the differences between the two operators)

Answer (score 3):

For PostgreSQL version > 9.6, you can simply run this:

```
UPDATE my_table 
set data = data::jsonb - 'attrB'
```

Comment: This is far too simple, yet the correct solution

Answer (score 2):

While this is certainly easier in 9.5+ using the jsonb operators, the function that pozs wrote to remove multiple keys is still useful.  For example, if the keys to be removed are stored in a table, you could use the function to remove them all.  Here is an updated function, using jsonb and postgresql 9.5+:

```
CREATE FUNCTION remove_multiple_keys(IN object jsonb, 
                                     variadic keys_to_delete text[], 
                                     OUT jsonb)
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
  LANGUAGE SQL
AS 
$$
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
     FROM (SELECT key, value 
           FROM jsonb_each("object")
           WHERE NOT (key = ANY("keys_to_delete")) 
     ) each_subselect
$$
;
```

If the keys to be removed are stored in a table, (e.g. in the column "keys" of the table "table_with_keys") you could call this function like this:

```
SELECT remove_multiple_keys(my_json_object, 
                            VARIADIC (SELECT array_agg(keys) FROM table_with_keys));
```

Answer (score 1):

One other convenient way of doing this is to use hstore extension.   This way you can write some more convenient function to set/delete keys into a json object.  I came up with following function to do the same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_key(json_in json, key_name text)
 RETURNS json AS $$
 DECLARE item json;
 DECLARE fields hstore;
BEGIN
 -- Initialize the hstore with desired key being set to NULL
 fields := hstore(key_name,NULL);

 -- Parse through Input Json and push each key into hstore 
 FOR item IN  SELECT row_to_json(r.*) FROM json_each_text(json_in) AS r
 LOOP
   --RAISE NOTICE 'Parsing Item % %', item->>'key', item->>'value';
   fields := (fields::hstore || hstore(item->>'key', item->>'value'));
 END LOOP;
 --RAISE NOTICE 'Result %', hstore_to_json(fields);
 -- Remove the desired key from store
 fields := fields-key_name;

 RETURN hstore_to_json(fields);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
STRICT;
```

A simple example of use is:

```
SELECT remove_key(('{"Name":"My Name", "Items" :[{ "Id" : 1, "Name" : "Name 1"}, { "Id" : 2, "Name 2" : "Item2 Name"}]}')::json, 'Name');
-- Result
"{"Items": "[{ \"Id\" : 1, \"Name\" : \"Name 1\"}, { \"Id\" : 2, \"Name 2\" : \"Item2 Name\"}]"}"
```

I have another function to do the set_key operation as well as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_key(json_in json, key_name text, key_value text)
RETURNS json AS $$
DECLARE item json;
DECLARE fields hstore;
BEGIN
 -- Initialize the hstore with desired key value
 fields := hstore(key_name,key_value);

 -- Parse through Input Json and push each key into hstore 
 FOR item IN  SELECT row_to_json(r.*) FROM json_each_text(json_in) AS r
 LOOP
   --RAISE NOTICE 'Parsing Item % %', item->>'key', item->>'value';
   fields := (fields::hstore || hstore(item->>'key', item->>'value'));
 END LOOP;
 --RAISE NOTICE 'Result %', hstore_to_json(fields);
 RETURN hstore_to_json(fields);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
STRICT;
```

I have discussed this more in my [blog](http://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2014/09/14/postgressql-json-add-delete-operation-functions/) here.

Answer (score 1):

It is an ugly hack but if `attrB` isn't your first key and it appears only once then you can do the following:

```
UPDATE my_table SET data = REPLACE(data::text, ',"attrB":' || (data->'attrB')::text, '')::json;
```

Comment: Not so bad. You could improve it with `regexp_replace` - make the comma optional and it would work in any case.

Comment: The problem with this is if the JSON expression evaluates to NULL (for example, the key does not exist), the entire string concatenation evaluates to NULL  due to the `||` operator, which then sets the entire JSON column to NULL. So if you run this on a JSON column with inconsistent data or accidentally type a key that doesn't exist, it will delete all your data. 

A better solution is using the `concat()` function which ignores NULL values, and thus won't destroy your data. 

`UPDATE my_table SET data = REPLACE(data::text, concat(',"attrB":' , (data -> 'attrB')::text), '')::json;`

Comment: I wasn't saying it is perfect, but it is a quick and dirty hack.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to find a simple update query that removed json keys in Postgres 9.4 without creating a function, so here's an update to @posz answer.

```
UPDATE someTable t
SET someField = newValue
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        json_object_agg(l.key, l.value)::text AS newValue
    FROM someTable t,
        LATERAL (
            SELECT *
            FROM json_each(t.someField::json)
            WHERE "key" <> ALL (ARRAY['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
        ) AS l
    GROUP BY id
) upd
WHERE t.id = upd.id
```

Query assumes you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    someField text
);
```

I guess you can use this line from @posz answer instead of json_object_agg line, to make it work on older postgres, but I didn't test it.

```
('{' || array_to_string(array_agg(to_json(l.key) || ':' || l.value), ',') || '}')::json AS after
```

Also make sure to run select from subrequest to make sure you're updating correct data

Comment: `UPDATE tenants t
SET config = newValue
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        json_object_agg(l.key, l.value)::text AS newValue
    FROM tenants t,
        LATERAL (
            SELECT *
            FROM json_each(t.config::json -> 'features')
            WHERE "key" <> ALL (ARRAY['edr'])
        ) AS l
    GROUP BY id
) upd
WHERE t.id = upd.id
and t.id = 100`

I want to iterate over the documents inside the features. Any idea how I could do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case

```
{"size": {"attribute_id": 60, "attribute_name": "Size", "attribute_nameae": "Size" "selected_option": {"option_id": 632, "option_name": "S"}}, "main_color": {"attribute_id": 61, "attribute_name": "Main Color", "selected_option": {"option_id": 643, "option_name": "Red"}}}
```

Remove size->attribute_nameae

```
UPDATE table_name set jsonb_column_name = jsonb_set(jsonb_column_name, '{size}', (jsonb_column_name->'size') -  'attribute_namea') WHERE <condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to remove JSON attribute not only from a single document but also from an array consider using statement like this:

```
    UPDATE table_to_update t
    SET jsonColumnWithArray = (SELECT JSON_AGG(jsonItem)
               FROM (SELECT JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(t1.jsonColumnWithArray)::JSONB #- '{customerChange, oldPeriod}' AS jsonItem
                     FROM table_to_update t1
                     WHERE t1.id = t1.id) AS t2);
```

Input

```
[
  {
    "customerChange": {
      "newPeriod": null,
      "oldPeriod": null
    }
  },
  {
    "customerChange": {
      "newPeriod": null,
      "oldPeriod": null
    }
  }
]
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "customerChange": {
      "newPeriod": null
    }
  },
  {
    "customerChange": {
      "newPeriod": null
    }
  }
]
```