# Sequelize: delete JSONB property (with PostgreSQL)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

I'm using [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) (v3.12.2), with [pg](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) (4.4.3), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) (v9.4), and [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) (v4.1.2).

I have a model that inlcudes a JSONB data type field.

```
var User = {
  data: {
    type: Sequelize.JSONB
}
```

Now I can do

```
User.findOne({where: {id: 12345}})
  .update({data: {x: 'foo'}});
```

And

```
User.findOne({where: {id: 12345}})
  .update({'data.y': 'bar'});
```

Now, if I want to delete just the `data.x` property how can I do it in one command?

```
User.findOne({where: {id: 12345}})
  .update({'data.x': null});
```

Obviously doesn't work. In fact, the resulting data object should be:

```
{y: 'bar'}
```

And not:

```
{x: null, y: 'bar'}
```

How can I do this with Sequelize? Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I think it's easier to restore the whole json object in "jsonb" field.. (but maybe it's not so effecient)

Answer (score 2):

If @Tarun Lalwani's code does not work, probably
Your postgresql 9.4 does not support "-" operation.

In that case, creating function or upgrade to 9.5+ would be your option.

See
[PostgreSQL: Remove attribute from JSON column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490965/postgresql-remove-attribute-from-json-column)

Comment: @Shamoon,  have you read this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490965/postgresql-remove-attribute-from-json-column

Comment: can you please add the relevant information to your answer so this post is complete?

Comment: JSONB type is postgresql data type. Sequence is ORM mapper to DB. If postgresql (9.4) does not support certain operation like "-" for JSONB, you can't use those operations in ORM mapper neither. But from v9.5 support the operation and in Sequence "-" operation work.

Answer (score 1):

I think below should work

```
User.findOne({where: {id: 12345}})
  .update({'data': sequelize.literal("data - 'x' ")});
```

Have not tested it, but if it doesn't work let me know. The solution will be along these lines only

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User.update({
        "data": sequelize.literal("data - 'x' ") 
    }, {
        where: {
            id: 12345
        }
    });
```

Comment: How is this different from existing answer?

Comment: It updates the database in a single Query. While yours does 2 queries. 1 to fetch the data and second to update.

Comment: This is more practical because it can bulk update any number of records with one query

Answer (score 0):

With Sequelize 6 (and maybe earlier), you can do the following on your model instance:

```
 delete myRecord.jsonBField.keyName;
```

Then call `changed` (required) to mark the field as changed and save:

```
 myRecord.changed("jsonBField", true);
 myRecord.save();`
```

Alternatively, you can call `myRecord.set("jsonBField.keyName", null)` to set the key to null, which will automatically mark the field as changed.