# how remove an element from json string column by activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have a table has a string column contains json data each record is like

```
{"id":1,"type":"car","name":"bmw"}
{"id":2,"type":"car","name":"Fiat"}
{"id":3,"type":"truck","name":"RAM"}
```

now I need to make a migration to remove name's element from json string by rails ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0] to becomes like this

```
{"id":1,"type":"car"}
{"id":2,"type":"car"}
{"id":3,"type":"truck"}
```

Comment: maybe [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490965/postgresql-remove-attribute-from-json-column) has what you need

Comment: not actually. Seems no body uses migrator to update records . somebody told me make a script and run it by rake . I don't know if it's best practice of doing that or not

Comment: I've done the same via a rake script. If you have a lot of records (50K +) it will take a long time and tie up one postgres connection and some memory, but the impact really is minor I believe. Use `find_each` to reduce the memory impact. And make sure you have an extra postgres connection to spare, otherwise you'll have server workers or background threads with no access to the DB when they need it.

Comment: yes exactly , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it by rake script

```
desc 'Remove name'
  task remove_name: :environment do
    Entry.all.find_each do |entry|
      puts "Removing #{entry.id}"
      entry.data.delete("name")
      entry.save
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 7):

If the database is Postgresql and the column is `jsonb`, then assuming you want to operate in the `car` table column

```rb
<MODEL_NAME>.update_all("car = car - 'name'")
```

It can be done via Rake task or a data migration

Comment: This is by far the superior solution. Takes milliseconds to perform on a large data set