# Postgres - Increment value in json

Tags: json, postgresql

Hello I have column of type JSON where I store for example '{ "foo": 0 }' now I would like to write trigger which will be increment value on specific action. I have problem because I don't know how increment or set 0 value if updated value not exist.
I tried to write function similar to code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563662/10999632 but It is not possible because:

```
ERROR:  function jsonb_set(json, unknown, jsonb) does not exist
LINE 2: SET payload = jsonb_set(payload, '{bar}', (COALESCE(payload-...
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your column `payload` is defined as `json`, not `jsonb`.

You need to cast the column to `jsonb` in order to be able to use `jsonb_set()`

```
SET payload = jsonb_set(payload::jsonb, '{bar}', ...)
```