# How to Django ORM update() a value nested inside a JSONField with a numeric value?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, django-jsonfield

I have a Django JSONField on PostgreSQL which contains a dictionary, and I would like to use the `queryset.update()` to bulk update one (eventually, several) keys with a numeric (eventually, computed) values. I see there is discussion about adding [better support for this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32519) and an [old extension](https://github.com/primal100/django_postgres_extensions#jsonfield), but for now it seems I need a DIY approach. Relying on those references, this is what I came up with:

```
from django.db.models import Func, Value, CharField, FloatField, F, IntegerField

class JSONBSet(Func):
    """
    Update the value of a JSONField for a specific key.
    """
    function = 'JSONB_SET'
    arity = 4
    output_field = CharField()

    def __init__(self, field, path, value, create: bool = True):
        path = Value('{{{0}}}'.format(','.join(path)))
        create = Value(create)
        super().__init__(field, path, value, create)
```

This seems to work fine for non-computed "numeric string" values like this:

```
# This example sets the 'nestedkey' to numeric 199.
queryset.update(inputs=JSONBSet('inputs', ['nestedkey'], Value("199"), False))
```

and for carefully quoted strings:

```
# This example sets the 'nestedkey' to 'some string'.
queryset.update(inputs=JSONBSet('inputs', ['nestedkey'], Value('"some string"'), False))
```

But it does not work for a number:

```
queryset.update(inputs=JSONBSet('inputs', ['nestedkey'], Value(1), False))

{ProgrammingError}function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, integer, boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "paiyroll_payitem" SET "inputs" = JSONB_SET("paiyroll...
                                                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

As per the HINT, I tried an explicit cast `Value(1, IntegerField())`. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Django functionality of Postgresql is just a fraction of what Postgresql is able to do.

Comment: I just came across a related question with an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957937.