# Check the value type of a JSON value in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-json

Let's say I have a json column fields, like so:

```
 {phone: 5555555555, address: "55 awesome street", hair_color: "green"}
```

What I would like to do is update all entries where the json key phone is present, and the result is of type number to be a string.

What I have is:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM parent_object
 WHERE (fields->'phone') IS NOT NULL;
```

Unfortunately this still returns values where `phone:null`. I'm guessing that a JSON `null` is not equivalent to a SQL `NULL`.

How do I 
1) How do I rule out JSON nulls
`AND (fields->'phone') <> null` produces

```
 LINE 4: ...phone') IS NOT NULL AND (fields->'phone') <> 'null';
 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

2) Check the type of the value at that key, this pseudocode `(type_of (fields->'phone') == Integer)` but in working PGSQL.

3) Modify this to update the column

```
 UPDATE parent_object
 SET fields.phone = to_char(fields.phone)
 WHERE  query defined above
```

Comment: Try `IS NOT NULL` instead of `<> NULL`

Comment: That fixes the first of my problems. Thank you. I'll rewrite the question to avoid confusing people. Any thoughts on the other two?

Comment: Why would you try to convert a phone to integer?! The value 5555555555 for example is **not** an integer, since it exceeds the (2^31)-1 limit.

Comment: trying to convert from a bigint to a string. Trying to allow human notation eg. + for country code, parens for area code et al

Comment: @KouberSaparev Not to mention `+61 8 # 9999 9999 *`. Phone numbers aren't just numbers.

Comment: @CraigRinger you are 100% correct kinda didn't really think that one through. In either case now trying to convert to the right format. Unfortunately my SQL is..... challenged

Comment: I do not get the whole idea. Why would you check whether something is a number, just to convert it to a string then?... The value type of a JSON value is already a varchar (a.k.a. string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As other folks have said, there is no reason to convert the variable to an integer just to them cast it to a string. Also, phone numbers are not numbers. :-)
2. You need to be using the `->>` operator instead of `->`. That alongside `IS NOT NULL` gets your SELECT query working.

   Note the difference between the two tuple values after running this query:

   ```
   SELECT fields->'phone', fields->>'phone'
   FROM parent_object;
   ```

   Your working query:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM parent_object
   WHERE (fields->>'phone') IS NOT NULL;
   ```
3. Postgres does not currently natively support atomically updating individual keys within a JSON column. You can write wrapper UDFs to provide this capability to you: [How do I modify fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype)

Answer (score 0):

For checking the type of the value at key, postgres has the following in the documentation.

json_typeof ( json ) → text
jsonb_typeof ( jsonb ) → text

Returns the type of the top-level JSON value as a text string. Possible types are object, array, string, number, boolean, and null. (The null result should not be confused with a SQL NULL; see the examples.)

json_typeof('-123.4') → number

json_typeof('null'::json) → null

json_typeof(NULL::json) IS NULL → t