# Does PostgreSQL have a mechanism to update the same row multiple times in a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Consider the following:

```
create table tmp.x (i integer, t text);
create table tmp.y (i integer, t text);
delete from tmp.x;
delete from tmp.y;
insert into tmp.x values (1, 'hi');
insert into tmp.y values(1, 'there');
insert into tmp.y values(1, 'wow');
```

In the above, there is one row in table `x`, which I want to update. In table `y`, there are two rows, both of which I want to "feed data into" the update.

Below is my attempt:

```
update tmp.x
set t = x.t || y.t
from ( select * from tmp.y order by t desc ) y
where y.i = x.i;

select * from tmp.x;
```

I want the value of `x.t` to be `'hiwowthere'` but the value ends up being `'hiwow'`. I believe the cause of this is that the subquery in the update statement returns two rows (the `y.t` value of `'wow'` being returned first), and the `where` clause `y.i = x.i` only matches the first row.

Can I achieve the desired outcome using a single `update` statement, and if so, how?

**UPDATE:** The use of the `text` type above was for illustration purposes only. I do not actually want to modify textual content, but rather JSON content using the `json_set` function that I posted here ([How do I modify fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/28686182#28686182)), although I'm hoping the principle could be applied to any function, such as the fictional `concat_string(column_name, 'string-to-append')`.

**UPDATE 2:** Rather than waste time on this issue, I actually wrote a small function to accomplish it. However, it would still be nice to know if this is possible, and if so, how.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to build up a concatenated string using [string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html), grouped by the `integer i`, which you can then join onto during the update:

```
update tmp.x
set t = x.t || y.txt
from (select i, string_agg(t, '') as txt
     from(
       select tmp.y.i,tmp.y.t
        from tmp.y
        order by t desc
      ) z
      group by z.i) y
where y.i = x.i ;
```

In order to preserve the order, you may need an additional wrapping derived table. [SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d9827/1)

Comment: It is possible to specify ordering in `string_agg` -  See Grisha's answer on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string_agg`, as follows:

```
update tmp.x x
set t = x.t || (
                select string_agg(t,'' order by t desc) 
                from tmp.y where i = x.i 
                group by i
               )
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0ba7/1)

Comment: Nice! - reference for options on [aggregates here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
select y.i, string_agg(t, '' order by t desc)  as txt
      from y
      group by y.i
)
update x set t= x.t||cte.txt 
from cte where cte.i=x.i
```