# PostgreSQL 9.4 to_jsonb

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

In PostgreSQL [9.5](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) `to_jsonb` function will be added. In [9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) there is only `to_json` function.

I'm trying to convert [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23500670/4335588) answer for jsonb but couldn't find an alternative for `to_json` function. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `to_json` and then cast it to `jsonb` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_jsonb(e anyelement)
RETURNS jsonb 
AS $$
    SELECT to_json(e)::jsonb
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

---

```
SELECT to_jsonb('Fred said "Hi."'::text),
       pg_typeof(to_jsonb('Fred said "Hi."'::text));
┌─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│      to_jsonb       │ pg_typeof │
├─────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ "Fred said \"Hi.\"" │ jsonb     │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┘
(1 row)
```

---

Naming this function `to_jsonb` is *probably* a bad idea though (since there will be a built-in `to_jsonb` in 9.5, and since it really easy to think this one is a built-in too).