# Insert/update JSON into Postgresql column WHERE myvar = myval

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm trying to insert JSON into a Postgresql column who's data type is JSON, but I'm having trouble finding how I can do this. This is as far as I've gotten but it's not correct because it just overwrites it every time, instead of adding a new key pair.

I'm using pg-promise node module to perform these queries. Here's what I have so far:

```
db.query("UPDATE meditation_database SET completed=$1 WHERE user_id=$2", [{myVar : true}, user_id]);
```

Also 'myVar' should be updated to the variable value, but instead it treats it as a string. How can I get the actual value of 'myVar' instead of it being treated literally.

Thanks,

Comment: For the last part, using variable `$1^` instead of `$1` will treat it as is, without formatting (see [raw-text variables](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#raw-text)). But PostgreSQL expects a string there. Updating JSON though is another question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to insert JSON into a Postgresql column who's data type is JSON, but I'm having trouble finding how I can do this.

By executing this:

```
db.query("INSERT INTO meditation_database(completed, user_id) VALUES($1, $2)", 
          [{myVar : true}, user_id]);
```

> Also 'myVar' should be updated to the variable value, but instead it treats it as a string. How can I get the actual value of 'myVar' instead of it being treated literally.

`myVar` is serialized into JSON as a string, that's the proper JSON format for property names, and is the only format that PostgreSQL will accept.

> This is as far as I've gotten but it's not correct because it just overwrites it every time, instead of adding a new key pair.

If you are asking how to update JSON in PostgreSQL, this question has been answered previously, and in great detail: [How do I modify fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype)