# SqlAlchemy(Flask+Postgres) : How to update only a specific attribute of a json field?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table that has one column declared as a json and I need to update records by adding a key-value to the json value.

**model**

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    loginId         = db.Column(db.String(128),  nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    _password       = db.Column(db.String(128),  nullable=True)
    views           = db.Column(JSON,         nullable=True)
```

**controller**

```
@mod_event.route('/view', methods=['POST'])
def view():
    try:
        params = request.json
        loginId = params['dream']['loginId']
        users.update().\
            where(users.c.loginId==loginId).\
            values(views=<query>))
```

Assume current value in `views` is {'1001' : 1} 
What should be the query if `views` has to be updated to -

- {'1001' : 2}
- {'1001' : 1, '1002' : 1}

if i don't want to query the value first, change and update back.

I'm having a hard time figuring how to do this in a single query, please help, thanks!

Comment: Updating the entire json field worked for me. Retrieved the json, modified it and saved it back.

Comment: Just for my understanding. Can you explain how you create `users` ?

Answer (score 6):

if you are using `JSONB`, you can use the `jsonb_set` function

```
(table
 .update()
 .values(views=func.jsonb_set(table.c.views,
                              '{%s}' % '1002',
                              1))
 .where(...))
```

if you are inserting from other column

```
(table
 .update()
 .values(views=func.jsonb_set(table.c.views,
                              '{%s}' % '1002',
                             other_table.c.other_column.cast(String).cast(JSONB)))
 .where(...))
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer! I'm trying to update the jsonb with another column however the cast into JSONB as you described does not work properly for strings. I always get a `InvalidTextRepresentation` error. I guess because the need to be multiple quotes `'"jsonb-value"'`. Any idea how to cast the value correctly? Thanks!

Comment: `cast('"'+other_table.c.other_column+'"', JSONB)` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

This way we can update new key-value pair in the views field.

```
from sqlalchemy import cast,func, JSON
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

users.query.filter(users.c.loginId==loginId).update({users.data: cast(
        cast(users.data, JSONB).concat(func.jsonb_build_object('1002', 1)), JSON)}, synchronize_session="fetch")
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype) for how to do it in SQL.

To do the same thing in Python (with PostgreSQL 9.5):

```
update().where(...)\
    .values(views=cast(cast(u.c.views, JSONB)
                       .concat(func.jsonb_build_object('1002', 1)), JSON)
```

For PostgreSQL 9.3+, you'll have to create the function in PostgreSQL first, then:

```
update().where(...)\
    .values(views=func.json_object_set_key(u.c.views, '1002', 1))
```