# Updating JSONField in django rest framework

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I currently became familiar with using JSONField in django rest-framework, but I could not find any straight forward way to update a key in a stored json. There are many ways to filter JSONField depends on its internal keys, but it seems that there is no way to change, update or delete a key from already stored JSONField. But it seems that postgres can do some modifications on json keys as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23500670/2335245) explained.

Is there any function which is able to do modifications on JSONFields. If there is not any direct command to do this, what is the best way to implement modifications of a JSONField?

**Edit:**

As an example if I have a model like this:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    properties = JSONField()
```

And in `properties` I stored a json like this :

```
{
"color" : "red",
"size" : "large",
"cost" : 1234
}
```

Then I want to change the color to "green" by using django commands.

Comment: Can you give an example of what sort of an update you are looking for. The easiest way is to read it into python, modify as a dictionary, and save.

Comment: @serg please see the edit note.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
thing = Thing.objects.get(name="...")
thing.properties['color'] = 'green'
thing.save()
```

Comment: Sorry I could not check your answer now, But I will check this as soon as possible and get you a feedback.

Comment: @serg I checked your answer, I think `properties` in `thing` is not something like dictionary or json (it is a `unicode`) so you need some middle operations to change it to a dictionary then again save it. It seems that django does not support this so I have to do something like you write here.

Comment: It is supposed to be a dictionary, are you using the latest Django, and Postgres db 9.4+? What is the value of the properties field, json as a string(unicode)? Also if you can go to the postgres console and check that your properties field type is `jsonb`.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, you are right in current version it is a dictionary, although yet in some situations it is not a dictionary that seems strange to me, but in most cases is a dictionary.

Comment: is there a way to do it with `.update()`?

Comment: @StriveForBest Check my answer.

Comment: General reference: `{"a": 1}` is valid JSON. If stored in a `JSONField`, it would be returned as a dictionary. However, `"some string"`, `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `true` are also valid JSON documents, which obviously would not be returned as dictionaries.

Answer (score 21):

The approach with `jsonb_set` from @tarasinf and @Vladius001 does also work with Django's [Func expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions).

```py
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value, JSONField

Thing.objects.update(
    properties=Func(
        F("properties"),
        Value(["color"]),
        Value("green", JSONField()),
        function="jsonb_set",
    )
)
```

Comment: This is the cleaner way for updating.

Comment: Be aware that **update method does instant commit**, so transaction rollbacks will not work. At least that's my experience.

Answer (score 2):

For your model:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    properties = JSONField()
```

If you need to update bunch of entries, you can do the following:

```
Thing.objects.update(
    properties=RawSQL("jsonb_set(properties, '{color}', 'green', true)", [])
)
```

`color: green` will be inserted, if not exists.

Welcome to [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html) for more information about `jsonb_set`.

Answer (score 0):

The next syntax works for me,

- Django==2.2.19
- Postgres==12.0.6

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
Thing.objects.update(properties=RawSQL("""jsonb_set(properties, \'{"name"}\',\'"name value"\', true)""", []))
```

Answer (score -4):

You can find better solution  here
https://django-postgres-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json.html

Comment: It didn't help that "__" at the end.