# How to allow a django end-user to create their own table in a controlled and secured way?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

This is regarding: **Django / Django ORM / POSTGRES**

**Goal:**
Allow an end-user to inherit from an existing model, create extra fields in it **or** create an entirely new model.

pseudo model code
**Example:**

OriginalModel

```
name = "Main Model"
Value_1 = "First Value"
```

User created variation

```
parent = OriginalModel
name = "Custom Model"
Value_1 = "First Value"
Value_2 = "Custom Additional Value"
```

I tried:

```
test_choices = (
    ('str', 'str'),
    ('num', 'num'),
)


class App(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class AppField(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey(App, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=test_choices, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
```

**Problem**
How do you allow a user to create an AppItem that uses fields in AppField as model fields?

Do you know a better way of doing this whole thing?

Comment: Clarification comment:

**Why would we do this?** a great use of this can be found in the app **[Podio][https://podio.com/]**


it allows you to create and customize your own to-do list app
 [https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcPjC.png ]


**then the end-user can simply add an app_item by filling out the fields like this**:
[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te4s6.png ]


Imagine a bunch of spreadsheets, a unique spreadsheet is an **App**, each column is an AppField, and each row is in AppItem

Comment: I'm pretty sure that podio.com uses JSON to form "user tables" (see [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield)) or something with a similar functionality. It would not be wise to allow users to mess with the basic database structure. You'd end up with a database that is a complete mess with thousands if not millions of tables of which most are probably stale / not in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd start to tackle this challenge with the use of JSONField (and PostgreSQL). It's just to give you a basic idea and I tried to follow Django principles. First two simple models. One to store model definitions as defined by users and one to store data.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.utils.text import slugify

class ModelDefinition(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    verbose_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    definition = JSONField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = slugify(self.verbose_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Data(models.Model):
    model_definition = models.ForeignKey(ModelDefinition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = JSONField()
```

Below is an example how you'd add model definitions, add and return data. I didn't include data validation since it would have taken me at least an hour to write code for basic validation.

`views.py`

```
from .models import ModelDefinition, Data
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

def create_model_definition(request):
    ''' Handles creation of model definitions '''

    model_definition = {
        'fields': [
            {
                'name': 'automobile',
                'verbose_name': 'Automobile',
                'data_type': 'string',
                'max_length': 50,
                'blank': False,
                'null': False
            },
            {
                'name': 'type',
                'verbose_name': 'Automobile type',
                'data_type': 'string',
                'max_length': 20,
                'blank': False,
                'null': False            
            },
            {
                'name': 'doors',
                'verbose_name': 'Number of doors',
                'data_type': 'integer',
                'blank': False,
                'null': False
            }
        ],
        'global_options': {
            'guest': {
                'verbose_name': 'Allow guests to enter data',
                'option': True
            },
            'public': {
                'verbose_name': 'Data is publicly accessible',
                'option': False
            }
        }

    }

    ModelDefinition.objects.create(
        user=request.user,
        verbose_name='My automobiles',
        definition=model_definition
    )

    return HttpResponse('model definition created')

def add_data(request, table='my-automobiles'):
    ''' Handles data entry  '''

    model_definition = get_object_or_404(ModelDefinition, user=request.user, name=table)
    if not request.user.is_authenticated and not model_definition.definition['global_options']['guest']['option']:
         return HttpResponse('Sorry, only authenticated users can enter data')

    data_rows = [
        {
            'automobile': 'Audi',
            'type': 'limousine',
            'doors': 4
        },
        {
            'automobile': 'Fiat',
            'type': 'hatchback',
            'doors': 3
        },
        {
            'automobile': 'Iveco',
            'type': 'truck',
            'doors': 2
        }      
    ]

    for row in data_rows:
        Data.objects.create(
            model_definition=model_definition,
            data=data
        )

    return HttpResponse('rows saved')

def show_data(request, table='my-automobiles'):
    ''' Returns data in JSON format '''

    model_definition = get_object_or_404(ModelDefinition, name=table)
    if not request.user.is_authenticated and not model_definition.definition['global_options']['public']['option']:
         return HttpResponse('Sorry, only authenticated users can view data')

    data = Data.objects.filter(model_definition__name=table)            
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Well, that's how I'd start working on this, no idea what I'd end up with. Of course, I haven't tested any of this code :)

Comment: Thanks! I guess that would work

I'm going to try this [ https://pastebin.com/bQnsSLEg ]; and store each row in a TestAppData table
so that 2 users can edit 2 different App rows at the same time without overriding each other, but we'll have to declare columns on each TestAppData item

Comment: Don't give up too soon on JSONField :) It's a perfect choice where dynamic structure is needed.

Comment: and pretty much do it like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680691/updating-jsonfield-in-django-rest-framework

Comment: @Sam, yes. Data from JSONField is converted to dictionary in Django.