# Update key value in JSONField()

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to bulk update lots of records (3.2 million).

This is my model:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    stats = JSONField()
```

Where stats is typically saved as:

```py
{ 
   "my_old_key": [{"hey": "Hello World"}]
}
```

I want to update it so that only the key changes it's value and final stats look like this (though there are records with `"my_new_key"` already so preferably skip those somehow):

```py
{ 
   "my_new_key": [{"hey": "Hello World"}]
}
```

I can do it in Python but it works really slowly.. I've tried on ~10k records with batching approach from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222176/why-is-iterating-through-a-large-django-queryset-consuming-massive-amounts-of-me/4222432#4222432) so that the queryset is not fetched entirely into the memory. Final solution looked like this:

```py
def update_queryset(queryset) -> None:
    for stat in queryset:
        dictionary = stat.stats
        if "my_old_key" in dictionary:
            dictionary["my_new_key"] = dictionary.pop("my_old_key")
        stat.save()
```

It does work but unfortunately it works too slowly :(.

I thought about not fetching it to python at all and working purely on database [somewhat like this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67983809/6087968) but didn't manage to make it work.

Any suggestions on how I can speed it up / write RawSQL / make the `jsonb_set` approach work?

EDIT:
I've filtered queryset before hand so as to skip additional if check but to no avail. Still works slowly..

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(stats__has_key="my_old_key")
...
def update_queryset(queryset) -> None:
    for stat in queryset:
        dictionary = stat.stats
        dictionary["my_new_key"] = dictionary.pop("my_old_key")
        stat.save()
```

Comment: Did you try with `transaction.atomic()` ?

Comment: Use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update

Comment: @codepylot I did just now, does not seem to make it any faster whether its used to wrap entire `update_queryset` method or `save()` call :(.

Comment: @EneP I know about bulk_update but I am not quite sure how to use it with `JSONField` the way I described. Could you please show me how could that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def update_queryset(queryset) -> None:
    for stat in queryset:
        stat.stats["my_new_key"] = stat.stats.pop("my_old_key")
    MyModel.objects.bulk_update(queryset, ['stats'])
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but this solution does not update the models IF i am using batching [link](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1170/) or using `queryset.iterator()` which I think I should be doing with 3.2 million records?

EDIT: It does seem work without batching.