# Appending to a JSONField using update_or_create in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to efficiently append a value to a `JSONField` (hobbies) in a Django model using the `update_or_create` method. I know it is easy to do this by initially calling the `update_or_create` method, then I get the `hobbies` field, append the information and the save again.

However, I want to avoid hitting the database twice. I tried using the `F()` expression but I'm getting `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3156, 'Invalid JSON value for CAST to DOUBLE from column history at row 1')`

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```py
# models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    hobbies = models.JSONField(default=list)
```

The code below is quite straight forward but I want to avoid hitting the DB twice

```py
user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(user=user)
user_profile.hobbies.append("Music")
user_profile.save()
```

I want to perform this action at a go so I tried the code below but it is raising `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3156, 'Invalid JSON value for CAST to DOUBLE from column history at row 1')`.

```py
user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(
    user=user,
    defaults={
        "hobbies": F("hobbies") + ["Music"]
    }
)
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I would actually advise *not* to use a JSON field. Relational databases are not good with JSON, and if the data is structured, like is the case here, it is often not a good idea, especially since it turns the database in non-normal form 1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Okay thanks, any suggestions?

Comment: A `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67983809/16770846) help?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem okay thanks

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon thanks but not really.