# How to update jsonb string with PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb, nosql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.5. I'd like to **update** a `jsonb` column.

My table is structured this way:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  gid    serial PRIMARY KEY,
  "data" jsonb
);
```

JSON strings are like this:

```
{"files": [], "ident": {"id": 1, "country": null, "type ": "20"}}
```

The following SQL doesn't do the job (syntax error - SQL state = 42601):

```
UPDATE my_table SET "data" -> 'ident' -> 'country' = 'Belgium';
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: `UPDATE my_table SET "data" = jsonb_set("data", '{"ident", "country"}', '"Belgium"');`

Comment: Actually duplicated: [How do I modify fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18209625/593144)

Comment: I agree but the question in the post your refer to is about `json` type (not `jsonb`). Answers widely refer to `jsonb`otherwise.

Comment: @Abelisto: Your query returns error message: *fonction jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, unknown) doesn't exist*. `jsonb_set()` function seems to be new to v. 9.5 (and I'm still using 9.4.5 as mentionned in my post).

Comment: Yep, I missed the `postgresql-9.4` tag. `jsonb_set` function was introduced in the 9.5 version. Dirty but easy way: `... SET "data" = regexp_replace("data"::text, , '"country":[^,^}]+', '"country": "Belgium"')::jsonb`

Comment: Good this worked fine! I just didn't understand what's between brackets for the regex `^,^}` ... Could you help on this point?

Comment: Any characters except comma and closing curve bracket. But remember that it is **dirty** solution and may fail for some JSON objects.

Comment: Right, thanks again...

Comment: @Abelisto Dirty indeed. For an almost equally dirty solution, but at least `json`-based, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok there are two functions:

```
create or replace function set_jsonb_value(p_j jsonb, p_key text, p_value jsonb) returns jsonb as $$
  select jsonb_object_agg(t.key, t.value) from (
    select 
      key, 
      case 
        when jsonb_typeof(value) = 'object' then set_jsonb_value(value, p_key, p_value)
        when key = p_key then p_value 
        else value 
      end as value from jsonb_each(p_j)) as t;
$$ language sql immutable;
```

First one just changes the value of the existing key regardless of the key path:

```
postgres=# select set_jsonb_value(
  '{"files": [], "country": null, "ident": {"id": 1, "country": null, "type ": "20"}}', 
  'country', 
  '"foo"');
                                   set_jsonb_value                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"files": [], "ident": {"id": 1, "type ": "20", "country": "foo"}, "country": "foo"}
(1 row)
```

```
create or replace function set_jsonb_value(p_j jsonb, p_path text[], p_value jsonb) returns jsonb as $$
  select jsonb_object_agg(t.key, t.value) from (
    select 
      key, 
      case
        when jsonb_typeof(value) = 'object' then set_jsonb_value(value, p_path[2:1000], p_value)
        when key = p_path[1] then p_value 
        else value 
      end as value from jsonb_each(p_j)
    union all
    select 
      p_path[1],
      case 
        when array_length(p_path,1) = 1 then p_value 
        else set_jsonb_value('{}', p_path[2:1000], p_value) end 
    where not p_j ? p_path[1]) as t;
$$ language sql immutable;
```

Second one changes the value of the existing key using the path specified or creates it if the path does not exists:

```
postgres=# select set_jsonb_value(
  '{"files": [], "country": null, "ident": {"id": 1, "type ": "20"}}', 
  '{ident,country}'::text[], 
  '"foo"');
                                   set_jsonb_value                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"files": [], "ident": {"id": 1, "type ": "20", "country": "foo"}, "country": null}
(1 row)

postgres=# select set_jsonb_value(
  '{"files": [], "country": null, "ident": {"id": 1, "type ": "20"}}', 
  '{ident,foo,bar,country}'::text[], 
  '"foo"');
                                            set_jsonb_value                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"files": [], "ident": {"id": 1, "foo": {"bar": {"country": "foo"}}, "type ": "20"}, "country": null}
(1 row)
```

Hope it will help to someone who uses the PostgreSQL < 9.5
Disclaimer: Tested on PostgreSQL 9.5

Answer (score 0):

In PG 9.4 you are out of luck with "easy" solutions like `jsonb_set()` (9.5). Your only option is to unpack the JSON object, make the changes and re-build the object. That sounds very cumbersome and it is indeed: JSON is horrible to manipulate, no matter how advanced or elaborate the built-in functions.

```
CREATE TYPE data_ident AS (id integer, country text, "type" integer);

UPDATE my_table
SET "data" = json_build_object('files', "data"->'files', 'ident', ident.j)::jsonb
FROM (
    SELECT gid, json_build_object('id', j.id, 'country', 'Belgium', 'type', j."type") AS j
    FROM my_table
    JOIN LATERAL jsonb_populate_record(null::data_ident, "data"->'ident') j ON true) ident
WHERE my_table.gid = ident.gid;
```

In the `SELECT` clause `"data"->'ident'` is unpacked into a record (for which you need to `CREATE TYPE` a structure). Then it is built right back into a JSON object with the new country name. In the `UPDATE` that `"ident"` object is re-joined with the `"files"` object and the whole thing cast to a `jsonb`.

A pure thing of beauty -- just so long as speed is not your thing...

Comment: IMO the main disadvantage of the your solution is that you rebuilds the whole object without taking in attention its initial structure which may be different.

Answer (score -1):

My previous solution relied on 9.5 functionality.

I would recommend instead either going with abelisto's solutions below or using pl/perlu, plpythonu, or plv8js to write json mutators in a language that has better support for them.

Comment: Your query returns error message: *fonction jsonb_build_object(unknown, unknown) doesn't exist*

Comment: sorry, misread the docs, should be json_build_object and then cast the final result to jsonb.  editing.

Comment: hmmm || also is 9.5 only.