# How to change the structure of the JSON field in the PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql

Array (name, value) to map.

```
[{'name':'email,'value':'email@email.em'},{'name':'phone','value':123123}]
```

to

```
{'email':'email@email.em','phone':123123}
```

I need to organize search and sorting such email and I would like to simplify to make `View` my `Table` with map data struct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I modify fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with t(id,j) as (
  values(1,'[{"name":"email","value":"email@email.em"},{"name":"phone","value":123123}]'::json))
select json_object_agg(a.j->>'name', a.j->>'value')
from t, json_array_elements(j) a(j) group by id;
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                  json_object_agg                   ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ { "email" : "email@email.em", "phone" : "123123" } ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks! this works.`select json_object_agg(a->>'name',a->>'value') from json_array_elements('[{"name":"email","value":"email@email.em"}, {"name":"phone","value":"123123"},{"name":"home","value":1}]') as a`

Comment: @happy_yar Yes it is simpler a bit and you can use it as a subquery in the `select` clause or as a source for the `update` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your input data to actually be json (dbl quotes instead on single and added keyname for array. After this transofrmation here is example of how to "build" it:

```
t=# with j as (
  select '{"arr":[{"name":"email","value":"email@email.em"},{"name":"phone","value":123123}]}'::json v
)
select
  concat('{',v->'arr'->0->'name',':',v->'arr'->0->'value',',',v->'arr'->1->'name',':',v->'arr'->1->'value','}')::json
from j
;
 {"email":"email@email.em","phone":123123}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this will not work because the number of pairs(name, value) can be different