# How do I modify a single property value inside the PostgreSQL JSONB datatype?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

How do I modify a single field inside the PostgreSQL JSONB datatype?

Let's say I have a table called animal like this:

```
id       info
------------------------------------------------------------
49493   {"habit1":"fly","habit2":"dive","location":"SONOMA NARITE"}
```

I'd like to simply change value(say, to upper case or lower case the text) of the location property. so the result, after UPDATE is

```
    id       info
------------------------------------------------------------
49493   {"habit1":"fly","habit2":"dive","location":"sonoma narite"}
```

I tried this below and it does not work

```
update animal set info=jsonb_set(info, '{location}', LOWER(info->>'location'), true) where id='49493';
----------------------------------
ERROR:  function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, text, boolean) does not exist
LINE 7: update animal set info=jsonb_set(info, '{con...
                                           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, text, boolean) does not exist
```

if I simply know what the updated value would be then I can use just use this:

```
update animal set info=jsonb_set(info, '{location}', '"sonoma narite"', true) where id='49493';
```

However, if the text value is unknown and we just want to do some simply operation such as append, prepend, upper/lower case, I can't simply find an answer to it.

I was surprised by the fact that jsonb set function does not offer such a trivial operation that only try to update the case of a text property inside a jsonb.

Can someone help?

Comment: I tried update test_table set info=jsonb_set(info, '{location}', '"cityTest"', true) where id='123'; but its still giving error as function does not exist. I'm using postgresql 9.4.8

Answer (score 22):

The third argument of `jsonb_set()` should be of `jsonb` type. The problem is in casting a text string to jsonb string, you need a string in double quotes. You can use `concat()` or `format()`:

```
update animal
set info = 
    jsonb_set(info, '{location}', concat('"', lower(info->>'location'), '"')::jsonb, true) 
--  jsonb_set(info, '{location}', format('"%s"', lower(info->>'location'))::jsonb, true) 
where id='49493'
returning *;

  id   |                               info                               
-------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 49493 | {"habit1": "fly", "habit2": "dive", "location": "sonoma narite"}
(1 row)
```

---

In **Postgres 9.4** you should unnest the json column using jsonb_each_text(), aggregate keys and values modifying the proper value on the fly, and finally build a json object:

```
update animal a
set info = u.info
from (
    select id, json_object(
        array_agg(key), 
        array_agg(
            case key when 'location' then lower(value)
            else value end))::jsonb as info
    from animal,
    lateral jsonb_each_text(info) 
    group by 1
    ) u
where u.id = a.id
and a.id = 49493;
```

If you can create functions this solution might be more pleasant:

```
create or replace function update_info(info jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select json_object(
        array_agg(key), 
        array_agg(
            case key when 'location' then lower(value)
            else value end))::jsonb
    from jsonb_each_text(info)
$$

update animal
set info = update_info(info)
where id = 49493;
```

Comment: Thanks! Klin, I will try that and let you know.

Comment: There is no token "someooopath" in my query. I'm not able to debug a query which I cannot see...

Comment: Hi klin, I think I found the issue in which it does not work. 
let's say if you have a underscore in the "location" property in the example above. postgres will throw error like "invalid input syntax for type json". Or if the value of this property does not have a space in it. It will throw error as well.

# This value under info column does not work
{"location":"MOCKUP_ATTRIBUTE"} 

# This value under info column does not work either
{"location":"MOCKUPATTRIBUTE"}

# This value under info column will WORK
{"location":"MOCKUP ATTRIBUTE"}

Comment: Yes, you're right. In these cases `quote_ident()` is not a good choice. Use `concat()` or `format()` instead. See the modified answer.

Comment: Hi klin,
I faced another issue with this. My dev machine has Postgres v9.6 which has jsonb_set function but our production server is using Postgres v9.4.5 which does not have jsonb_set function. So I can't use this script. 

 if you don't mind, would you help with or give me some suggestion about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Klin, thanks so much for your updated answer for Postgres v9.4. This is almost to what I need exactly except the fact that I noticed an issue with this approach (,   if the jsonb has nested object like this { "attrib1": { "land": { "action" : "walk" }, "location" : "someplace" }, the nested part of the jsonb has extra back slash "\" escape character. 
I am totally new on writing sql function so I have yet to figure out how to deal with this... :((

Comment: An example that expose this nested json property issue:

  select json_object(
        array_agg(key), 
        array_agg(
            case key when 'location' then lower(value)
            else value end))::jsonb
    from json_each_text('{"a":"foo", "location":"LONDON UK", "c" :{ "d": "dog"}}') \n
------------------------------------------\n
"{"a": "foo", "c": "{ \"d\": \"dog\"}", "location": "london uk"}"

Comment: It's quite another matter. I'd suggest to delete these comments and ask a new question concerning the issue (btw, it's quite difficult in Postgres 9.4).

Comment: Never mind, klin,
I think I've found out a way to deal with it with v9.4. Thanks anyway!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5):

Some good news here I'd like to share. Thanks to klin, His input helped me discover this solution. In example above. if I simply use concat function, then the issue that I found in the code that klin posted is resolved (in short, it works only if the text value contains spaces). Now I can lower case a single property value!

```
UPDATE test1 set info=jsonb_set(info, '{location}', concat('"',lower(info->>'locatioin'),'"')::jsonb, true) returning *;
```