# Editing a jsonb value in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column that stores values like this:

`{"v":"0","c":"ACC",...}`

I'd like to update some of the `v` values to `1`

Is there any built-in function to do that in postgresql?

E: I'm using v9.6

Comment: [jsonb_set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: or `||` operator: `column || '{"v":"1"}'`

Comment: I'd say you want to modify a value, not a key then?..

Comment: @VaoTsun yes, I've updated the question. I want to change the values

Comment: Both suggestions (`jsob_set` and `||`)  that [are documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)  will do what you want

Comment: wouldn't it be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Postgresql 9.5

```
UPDATE test SET data = data - 'v' || '{"v":1}' WHERE data->>'c' = 'ACC';
```

OR

```
UPDATE test SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{v}', '1'::jsonb);
```