# How to perform update operations on columns of type JSON in Postgres 9.3?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

As an example, I have this basic table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id serial, info json);
INSERT INTO test(info)
   VALUES ('{
             "dept":[
                     {
                      "name":"abc",
                      "desc":"hello",
                      "enabled":false
                     },
                     {
                      "name":"xyz",
                      "desc":"hello",
                      "enabled":false
                     }
                    ]
            }');
```

I want to update and set `"enabled":true` where `"name"` is `"abc"`.

Comment: Hope this Link Will Help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype

Comment: JSONB datatype is not available in 9.3 , So I need to update it without JSONB.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL 9.3 only has functions to create JSON, but no functions to use or modify it. I've already faced it before and I used the 2 trick below

1. Cast it into text and use function `regexp_replace`. See the query below

   ```
   SELECT info, 
          regexp_replace(info::text,
                         '("name":"abc"[^}]+)"enabled":false',
                         E'\\1"enabled":true'
                        )::json 
   FROM test;
   ```

   More explanation: the `\\1` represents the characters matched between `(` and `)` in the search string. You can find more information [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-EMBEDDED-OPTIONS-TABLE).
2. Newer versions of PostgreSQL have functions to modify JSON. So install a small instance of PostgreSQL in a newer version and use the features “foreign table” or “dblink” to update the data with the primary key. For the functions to update `json` and `jsonb` you can get more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype).

Hopefully it'll help you in this case.