# Extra a string value and update the string value in Postgres SQL

Tags: json, postgresql

There is a column in one of my tables which contains the value like

```
{"firstname":"aaa","secondname:"bbb","lastname":"ccc","age":"18","Address:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

1. I am in need of SQL query to extract the value secondname (here the value will be bbb)
2. and I also  need a update query to set the second value as empty
   the output will be like

```
{"firstname":"aaa","secondname:"","lastname":"ccc","age":"18","Address:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I modify fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype)

Comment: In my tables  the data type for my column as text.