# How to modify field with jsonPath in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

How to modify a field using jsonPath in PostgreSQL like SQL Server JSON_MODIFY (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Thanks!

Comment: `jsonb_set()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: jsonb_set does not support jsonPath, it has a different path format

Comment: Well, that's the only way to modify a JSON value in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no ways to update JSON properties using JsonPath. The only way is with jsonb query [jsonb_set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: That's not correct anymore since PostgreSQL 14, see this answer to a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71794798/4300087