# How to update multiple nested keys in a json field in single update query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb

I'm trying to write a function that updates a `json` (not `jsonb`) field (called `settings`) in a table (called `user`).

My json object looks like this (however it might not have some of the keys on any nesting level):

```json
{
  "audiences": ["val1", "val2"],
  "inviteNumber": "123",
  "workExperience": [
    {
      "company": {
        "name": "Ace",
        "industry": "Accounting",
        "revenues": "1M-10M",
        "size": "1-10"
      },
      "title": "Product",
      "startDate": {
        "month": 1,
        "year": 2018
      }
    }
  ],
  "notifications": {
    "emailNotifications": true
  },
  "jobFunction": "Research & Development",
  "phoneNumber": "2134447777",
  "areasOfInterest": {
    "Recruiting and Staffing": true
  }
}
```

I need to be able to update the "title" and "name" fields of the 0th element inside "workExperience" array.

What I currently have is this:

```sql
create or replace function my_function()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare
    companyName character varying(255);
begin
    select company.name into companyName from company where id = new.companyid;

    update "user" set
        email = new.email,
        "settings" = jsonb_set(
            "settings"::jsonb,
            '{workExperience,0}'::TEXT[],
            format(
                '{"company": {"name": %s}, "title": %s}',
                '"' || companyName || '"', '"' || new.title || '"'
            )::jsonb
        )
    where id = new.userid;
    
    return new;
end $$;
```

However the above implementation rewrites the while `workExperience` object removing the keys other than `company` and `title`.

I've tried looking through [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23500670/4674270), but still wasn't able to implement the updating correctly.

I see that the problem is with how the `jsonb_set` works and it does just what I tell it to do: set 0th element of "workExperience" array to the object I define inside `format` function.
Seems like I need to use multiple `jsonb_set` one inside another, but I can't figure out the way to do it correctly.

---

How can I update my json field correctly without removing other keys from the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsonb_set() returns the modified JSON value.

You could nest the calls and change the company name first, and use the result of that as the input to another jsonb_set().

```
"settings" = jsonb_set(jsonb_set("settings"::jsonb, '{workExperience,0,company,name}', to_jsonb(companyname)), 
                       '{workExperience,0,title}', to_jsonb(new.title)
                      )
```

Comment: For some reason it gives me `could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"` without much context. I've tried casting paths by doing `::TEXT[]` but to no avail

Comment: It's most likely the `to_jsonb()` function. Try `to_jsonb(new.title::text)` and `to_jsonb(companyname::text)`

Comment: Brilliant, it worked! Thanks a lot. I've always struggled with this type casting problems