# Standardize date of birth in JSON in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a mix of date of births in my database. Some are of the format `yyyyy-mm-dd` and some are of form `mm:dd:yyyy`. I am trying to calculate age and that makes it difficult for me to do date. How can i standardize the dates?

```
SELECT date_of_birth 
  FROM ( SELECT attrs::JSON->'info'->>'date_of_birth' 
           FROM users ) AS date_of_birth;

date_of_birth      
--------------
 (2000-11-03)
 (2000-06-11)
 (2000-05-31)
 (2008-11-26)
 (2007-11-09)
 (2020-03-26)
 (2018-06-30)
 (02:21:2020)

 (2007-10-09)
```

There are only a couple of `mm:dd:yyyy` date of births. I tried updating the field in the JSON by

```
UPDATE users 
   SET attrs::JSON->'info'->>'date_of_birth'='02-21-2020' 
 WHERE attrs::JSON->'info'->>'date_of_birth'='02:21:2020'
```

but its erroring out

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"

Comment: There is, a very long, answer here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype ) If that does not answer your question, then Please add some sample data and your table structure. (like is explained in [mre])

Comment: This is a good reason to have a properly normalized database, e.g. with a `date_of_birth` table attribute of type `date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the data type of `attrs` from `JSON` to `JSONB`

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN attrs 
  SET DATA TYPE JSONB USING attrs::JSONB
```

Then, update the related data(which contains semi-colon within the `date_of_birth` data) by using `JSONB_SET()` function such as

```
UPDATE users
   SET attrs = JSONB_SET( attrs, '{info,date_of_birth}', 
                          ('"'||TO_DATE(
                                  attrs::JSONB->'info'->>'date_of_birth', 'mm:dd:yyyy'
                                  )::TEXT||'"')::JSONB 
                        )
  WHERE POSITION( ':' IN attrs::JSON->'info'->>'date_of_birth'::TEXT ) > 0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1f91a0b79629229a8760be5b205ccc5c)</kbd>